# Cops: There's a fault in my vault!

Tags: code-golf, cops-and-robbers

In this game of cops and robbers, each cop will make a vault: a program that stores a secret, and requires a key to unlock. The robbers should find a way to get the vault to reveal its secret without knowing the key.

### Cop rules

Cops will write two short segments of code:

- A vault, which takes a key and secret, then allows a robber to guess the key

  - One way to do this would be to use a class, which is constructed with a key and secret, and has a method to enter guesses into
  - The poster should specify a certain set of valid keys and secrets, such as 32 bit integers or strings (note that, unless you add code to prevent it, robbers can still input things that aren't in that set as part of their crack)
  - When a correct guess is made, the vault should return the secret. Otherwise, it should return nothing or a deterministic value that isn't a valid secret
  - Can **not** rely on cryptographic functions, or any system that can only (realistically) be defeated by brute forcing a value
  - Any code necessary to create an instance of the vault does not count toward the byte count (such as `let vault = faulty_vault("key", "secret");`
- A fault, which makes the vault reveal its secret

  - Should work for all keys and secrets
  - Should follow the robber rules

Cop submissions should contain the following information:

- The name of the language used
- The byte count
- The format of the keys and secret
- The maximum number of guesses needed for the fault (to prevent brute forcing)
- The code for the vault

### Robber rules

**Robbers will post their cracking attempts as answers in a separate thread, located [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210639/robbers-theres-a-fault-in-my-vault).**

- Should work for all keys and secrets
- Should require the same number or fewer guesses as the cop's fault, to prevent brute forcing
- Does not need to be the same as the cop's intended fault
- Multiple cracks may be made for the same cop, as long as they use different methods

### Example

**Cop:**

> ### Javascript (V8), too many bytes
>
> Maximum **2** guesses.
>
> Keys and secrets may be any string
>
> ```js
> function faulty_vault(key, secret) {
>     return function(guess) {
>         if (guess.constructor != String)
>             return;
>
>         if (guess == key || typeof(guess) != "string") // Second condition is impossible...right?
>             return secret;
>     };
> }
> ```

**Robber:**

> ### [Javascript (V8)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)
>
> Uses 1 guess
>
> ```js
> // Assumes vault instance is in variable "vault"
>
> var not_a_string = new String("typeof thinks this isn't a string");
> vault(not_a_string);
> ```

The winner is the shortest cop not cracked after seven days (safe). Good luck!

Comment: So are the fault and the vault 2 separate pieces of code? Also, can we use type parameters and implicit parameters and all of that?

Comment: Another question: Can the input be a higher-order function, an instance of some other class, instead of a number or string?

Comment: @user Yes, fault and vault are separate pieces of code, assume it's run in the order vault -> instance created of vault -> fault/crack/robber. You can use type/implicit parameters and inputs can be any type you want as long as it's listed in the cop submission.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. For the "set of valid keys and secrets" part, does this mean we give a list like `[("key1", "secret1"), ("key2","secret2")]` or do we just say "Keys can be strings, secrets can be strings"?

Comment: @user Either. You just need to let the robbers know how the vault expects keys and secrets. "all keys are integers, all secrets are strings", "all keys are integers, and all secrets are integers twice the size of the keys", and "all keys will be 4, 5, or 6. all secrets will be 7, 8, or 9, respectively" would all be valid.

Comment: I'm confused by what the intention is with vaults and multiple guesses. Is it just meant to be "Find an input that makes a given function output True"? That is, the vault dispenses the key only if the input passes this test. That's what the example looks like. What might a cop look like that uses multiple guesses, or where the secret itself is used in a meaningful way?

Comment: @xnor Think the `vault` in the example as an instance of a class. When it's instantiated, it's given a `key`, and a `secret`. When a method of the class (or, in the example, the returned function) is called, it would test if a `guess` is equal to the `key`, and return the `secret`. The cop should make it so there's a way to get the `secret` without knowing the `key`. An example using multiple guesses might be a class where the guess validating method "accidentally" reveals the key or secret in a public property. I guess you could make the secret affect the cop, but it's not known to the robber

Comment: Oh, so is the validating function supposed to only check whether the guess equals the key (if not for the fault)? That is, it shouldn't check some more complicated property of the guess or guesses?

Comment: Also, is the fault allowed to do underhanded things like overwriting the vault methods or extracting its key directly? A trivial Python example: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BDoMgEETP@hUbetHEeOixib/QW3slBNdKIGgATfx6uohtPfSyYd/MzjBvYZzsNUZphPfwFIsJt7LocQDOlVWB88qjGRrQuDXgUToMNTmKRFuC0CXpA7KBWH6UOeq1oPecbEfWvu8p6hChSyc5MfGCjhdn4RRKFI3Hs3qfLMaV2vZ/V0yzBphndTk7ZQOs7a@Yif9YEy4vwB62RzcKmj0D6YTUX3euj28 "TIO") Or is the idea that it interacts solely by querying key guesses to the vault as a black box?

Comment: @xnor Yes, it is allowed to do that. Languages without private variables may not work for this challenge /:

Comment: I don't think any language without classes or closures would work for this neatly.

Comment: I don't get how you can possibly write an interesting cop challenge if you allow extracting the key directly. What's to prevent me using runtime reflection, or introspecting `/proc/self/mem`?

Comment: *When a correct guess is made, the vault should return the secret. Otherwise, it should return nothing or a deterministic value that isn't a valid secret* - Does it mean I'm allowed to give a result that depends on the guess when it is wrong, e.g. let the robber play Mastermind?