# Robbers: There's a fault in my vault!

Tags: code-golf, cops-and-robbers

**This is the robbers' thread. The cops' thread is located [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210638/cops-theres-a-fault-in-my-vault).**

### Robber rules

- Should work for all keys and secrets
- Should require the same number or fewer guesses as the cop's fault, to prevent brute forcing
- Does not need to be the same as the cop's intended fault
- Multiple cracks may be made for the same cop, as long as they use different methods

### Find Uncracked Cops

```html
<script>site = 'meta.codegolf'; postID = 5686; isAnswer = false; QUESTION_ID = 210638;</script><script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script>jQuery(function(){var u='https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/';if(isAnswer)u+='answers/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJeRCD';else u+='questions/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJO6t)';jQuery.get(u,function(b){function d(s){return jQuery('<textarea>').html(s).text()};function r(l){return new RegExp('<pre class="snippet-code-'+l+'\\b[^>]*><code>([\\s\\S]*?)</code></pre>')};b=b.items[0].body;var j=r('js').exec(b),c=r('css').exec(b),h=r('html').exec(b);if(c!==null)jQuery('head').append(jQuery('<style>').text(d(c[1])));if (h!==null)jQuery('body').append(d(h[1]));if(j!==null)jQuery('body').append(jQuery('<script>').text(d(j[1])))})})</script>
```

Comment: VTCing as the cops part is closed