# Guess my password (cops' thread)

Tags: code-golf, cops-and-robbers

*Inspired by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/210638/95792) challenge, which got closed. This is meant to be an easier, but no less interesting version of that.*

This is the cops thread of a [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge. For the robbers thread, see [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/213963/95792).

Cops will provide a program/function and a flag. Robbers will try to guess a password such that, when the password is given to the cop's program, the flag is outputted.

## Basic rules

- The language used should be provided.
- The flag, which can be an integer, string, or value of any other type, should be provided.
- The flag may be printed to STDOUT, returned from a function, or outputted using any of the other standard output methods, as long as you specify how it will be outputted.
- The program/function can take the password through STDIN, as a function argument, or using any of the other standard input methods, as long as you specify how the it will be inputted.
- A free online compiler/interpreter should also be linked, preferably with the cop's code already pasted in and ready to run.

## Some more rules

- There must be at least one valid password that causes your program to return the flag, and you should know at least one of those passwords when posting your answer.
- In case of a function submission, the cop should *also* include a full runnable program including the function either in the answer or in the linked online compiler/interpreter.
- If it is at all ambiguous what the type of the flag is, it must be specified.
- If a cop's description of the output is ambiguous (e.g. "`HashSet(2, 1)` should be printed"), robbers are allowed take advantage of that (e.g. print the string "HashSet(2, 1)" instead of an actual hashset)
- Forcing robbers to simply brute force the password is not allowed.
- The program must take input, and must output the flag when given the correct password. When not given the correct password, you are free to error, output something else, or immediately terminate. If your program never halts if given the wrong password, you must tell robbers of this behavior so no one waits around for the program to output something.

Cops's score will be the number of bytes their code takes up.

Cop answers will be safe if they haven't been cracked for two weeks.

## Example

Cop:

> ## Scala, 4 bytes
>
> ```
> x=>x
> ```
>
> Flag: `Yay, you cracked it!` (an object of type `String` is returned from the lambda above)
> [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUM2loFCWmKOQZqUQXFKUmZeuYGsHZ/2vsLWr@A9RkF6aWlysYKugFFBaolCZX1oEFclILUpVAhpSANRSkpOnkaYBFtfU5Kr9DwA)

Robber:

> Password: the string "Yay, you cracked it!"
> [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUM2loFCWmKOQZqUQXFKUmZeuYGsHZ/2vsLWr@A9RkF6aWlysYKugFJlYqaNQmV@qkFyUmJydmqKQWaKoBDSlAKinJCdPI00DrFRTk6v2PwA)

## Find Uncracked Cops

```html
<script>site='meta.codegolf';postID=5686;isAnswer=false;QUESTION_ID=213962;</script><script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script>jQuery(function(){var u='https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/';if(isAnswer)u+='answers/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJeRCD';else u+='questions/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJO6t)';jQuery.get(u,function(b){function d(s){return jQuery('<textarea>').html(s).text()};function r(l){return new RegExp('<pre class="snippet-code-'+l+'\\b[^>]*><code>([\\s\\S]*?)</code></pre>')};b=b.items[0].body;var j=r('js').exec(b),c=r('css').exec(b),h=r('html').exec(b);if(c!==null)jQuery('head').append(jQuery('<style>').text(d(c[1])));if (h!==null)jQuery('body').append(d(h[1]));if(j!==null)jQuery('body').append(jQuery('<script>').text(d(j[1])))})})</script>
```

Comment: This is already explicitly mentioned in the challenge, but [here is the meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19323/58563) from _Loopholes that are forbidden by default_ about using cryptographic functions in CnR challenges.

Comment: May we specify multiple output formats at once; that is, specify that STDOUT must be `a` and STDERR must be `b`?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Sure, as long as it doesn't get too crazy

Comment: I am assuming that the program can get into an infinite loop when given a wrong password, right?

Comment: Oh, then that makes my to-be answer wrong! :(

Comment: Can there be any condition for the password, like "The password is a multiple of 34"?

Comment: @SunnyMoon Sure, you can tell robbers that the password is a multiple of 34. Whether it's wise to leave robbers that clue, I don't know :)

Comment: What is your definition of cryptographic functions?

Comment: @thedefault. I couldn't find anything good on Meta, but I guess hashes and other stuff that can't be reverse-engineered without brute force

Comment: This challenge seems to amount to just do cryptography without using cryptography.

Comment: @WheatWizard How so? I meant for cops to exploit language features, dodge regex in clever ways, etc. If someone wants to post an answer which one can only crack through brute force, they can do that, but it's against the spirit of this challenge.

Comment: This is the exact task that cryptography is intended to solve.  I'm not sure how you wanting answers to be clever changes that.

Comment: @WheatWizard It's a [standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19323/95792), and it doesn't look like most answers are doing that anyways.

Comment: Yeah, you want people to do cryptography without cryptography.  That's my point.

Comment: @WheatWizard I don't think forcing people to get around input validation counts as cryptography. If you want, I can change "Using cryptographic functions is not allowed" to "Forcing robbers to simply bruteforce passwords is not allowed"

Comment: I don't see how that would help anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115498/discussion-between-user-and-wheat-wizard). @WheatWizard

Comment: I posted my problem but no one has succeded to crack mine; should I reveal my password already?

Comment: @tailsparkrabbitear If it's safe, go ahead. If not, you should wait.

Comment: If the code is a function, are we allowed to put restrictions on what the password is? For example, in JS, if my submission was `x=>(x+"").split(",")` with a flag of `["a","b"]`, it could be cracked both by `"a,b"` and by `(String.prototype.split=()=>["a","b"],"")`. Could I restrict the password to simple string literals and exclude a computation like that, or would I have to submit it as a whole program to get that restriction?

Comment: @tjjfvi I'm going to say no to that, sorry.

Answer (score 17):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 89 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214020/48931) by [Benkerd22](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98889/benkerd22)

```php
<?php
$x=file_get_contents('php://stdin');
if(!preg_match('/.*golf.*/',$x))echo trim($x);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclJCoAgFADQvacoCByI3DfQUSTsO0DpR//C21vLx8OAve8nBmRTO1x8wHggY3MiSFQF/2fVutIdE5cbi06MWMCb9yIbBNeL8vlxi9J8npqUYEMeqMRX/Np6/wA)

Outputs `golf`, exactly.

Comment: I have a feeling this requires newlines

Comment: I assume the intended output `golf` doesn't contain any hidden unprintables? I.e. [this isn't valid?](https://tio.run/##DclLCoAgEADQfacoCNSI3Peho0jY@AHTIWfRshN1qC5iLR8PHZYyr@iwaq/F@ADKAimdIkGkzNk/o5SZdh@ZmCpveIMnWHVspB1ncuhsCmboJOvbSwjQLtV0@oP/mkp578eEZD8)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That's correct, there's no hidden characters. If you piped the output into xxd you would get precisely `67 6f 6c 66`.

Comment: [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214020/98889)

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 94 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214005/39531) by [Christian Mann](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39531/christian-mann)

<sup>Edited to reduce score. See [revision history](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/213978/revisions) for ungolfed version.</sup>

Another Python answer.

```python
import re,sys
p=sys.stdin.read()
if re.match('^[exc\dhrkb\slim_=:;,.ants]*$',p):exec p;print a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclBCsMgEEDRfU7homBSREKXCTlJkxarUxxazTDOwpzeBrr5PPh0SNzzrTVMtLMoBlOO0tFy1hYJmC2DC/3Q4fucNjnxsdePO1S/hsif11q@mJ7LNBvrspTtetGGhgkqeEUzMWZRrrU/9Fj9GED/AA)

Flag is `0xc0de`. The output should be to STDOUT.

---

My solution was basically the same as Christian's:

The regex only accepts a very limited number of characters. Notable exclusions are all kinds of brackets, string delimiters, almost all operators and the `p` for `print` and `input`.
`a='0xc0de'` doesn't match the regex, and `a=hex(49374)` neither.

With these restriction I don't know of a way to call any function that returns a value. I would be interested in counterexamples ;).
<sup>One exception is `a==b`, which calls `a.__eq__(b)`, but since `q` is not available, you can only do this with builtin types.</sup>

The idea is to use the fact that `print a` calls `a.__str__` to get a string representation of the object `a`. This means we need to define an object `a` with a custom `__str__` method, which is then called by string.
Instantiating objects is not possible without `()`, but luckily we can define methods on classes rather than instance objects using metaclasses.
The metaclass is required to have an `__init__` function, that takes three arguments and returns `None`. A good choice for this is an `__init__` function of a different class.

This result into the final solution:

```python
class b:
    __str__ = 49374 .__hex__
    __init__ = 0 .__init__
class a:
    __metaclass__ = b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PzknsbhYIcmKSwEI4uOLS4ri4xVsFUwsjc1NFPTi4zNSK@LjoZKZeZklYFkDkAyExwUxIBFmQG5qSSJYCKww6X9BUWZeiULifwA)

This doesn't work in Python 3 for two reasons:

- `int`'s dont have a `__hex__` method anymore.
- The syntax for metaclasses has changed. In Python 3 this would look like `class a(metaclass=b): ...`, which uses forbidden brackets

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214005/39531)

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/), 189 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213970/15100) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)

```python
import re

inp = raw_input()
if not re.match(r"^[\w\d=]*$", inp):
    quit()
exec(inp)

a = raw_input()
b = raw_input()
flag = a == b

if flag == True:
    print("%s %s"%(a, b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BDsIgDIbvfYqGSAJm8WDixYSrT@DNqYHJHIkDZJDp0yO423po2q9f/vpvHJzd52xG70LEoAGM9SgwyPlephQZB9OjdfW4G2XsBhbI7dLO7UNctxvSYNH4EbDUO5nq64/uWKUAchWlVnv/ks@CiiZQQf20EIHnkPSS6oOxkRE6IZ0IZbJBxXnOUhzgVOR/@wE)

Flag is `The Flag`, output to STDOUT. This might be a bit easy, but hopefully still fun!

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213970/64121)

Comment: Nice! I knew it was too easy...

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 60 bytes, [cracked by Paul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214194/86301)

```r
function(x) chartr("zyxwvu", "RRRRRR", tolower(x[1] + x[2]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCr8D@tNC@5JDM/T6NCUyE5I7GopEhDqaqyorysVElHQSkIDICskvyc/PLUIo2KaMNYBW2FimijWE3N/2kahlZGmv8B)

As in [my previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213985/86301), the flag to output is the string `"R"`. In other words, you need to find `x` such that `f(x)=="R"` is `TRUE`.

---

The solution is e.g. `as.roman(c(2, 3))`. This object is represented as `c(II, III)`; it is of mode `numeric` but of class `roman`. Since it is numeric, addition works, giving the roman integer `V`. But since it is of class roman, `tolower` coerces it to string, giving the string `"v"`. Then `chartr` translates this to `"R"`.

Comment: What's the best way to write google queries about "R"?

Comment: @EricDuminil Often, including "R" in the search is enough. You can also include "CRAN" in the search (the Comprehensive R Archive Network), or search the `r` tag on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r

Comment: @Robin: I can crack this if I'm allowed to call the function twice (in which case, only the second call cracks it).  Is that allowed (or what you intended...)?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Only one function call is needed, and a second call is not allowed. But I'm still curious to hear what you had in mind!

Comment: Oh, well, [here](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCr8D@tNC@5JDM/T6NCUyE5I7GopEhDqaqyorysVElHQSkIDICskvyc/PLUIo2KaMNYBW2FimijWE3N/2ka1QnaCTa6IGSdrGGsY6xZq8mFJqpUoaQDxECZ/wA) it is: password1 (fails) = ```{`+`<-`<-`;c(3,3)}```, password2 (works) = ```{`+`<-`<-`;c("x","x")}```.  I'll keep trying...

Comment: Q2: can our function call cause an error, if it outputs the correct 'flag' and doesn't output anything else (except to STDERR)?

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214135/95126), although I suspect that this wasn't your intended solution...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I'm afraid that your crack isn't valid (and I had thought of that loophole): you are printing `"R"`, but the output is empty. The password is an object `x` such that `f(x)=="R"` is `TRUE`.

Comment: Ah, yes, I think you're right.  I'll delete the 'crack' & keep thinking.  Darn!

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I've updated the question to make this completely explicit. Also, a simpler version of your proposal with 2 calls is [this](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCr8D@tNC@5JDM/T6NCUyE5I7GopEhDqaqyorysVElHQSkIDICskvyc/PLUIo2KaMNYBW2FimijWE3N/2ka1Wk2usnWRakFGn6hPj46Rpq1mlxpGkpBSpr/AQ "R – Try It Online"). It would probably work for any other function-based R challenge, so all the more reason to disallow it!

Comment: Yes, agreed.  I had in mind that it would make future variants difficult...

Comment: [Cracked!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCr8D@tNC@5JDM/T6NCUyE5I7GopEhDqaqyorysVElHQSkIDICskvyc/PLUIo2KaMNYBW2FimijWE3N/2kaicV6Rfm5iXkayRqGOgqWmkBBAA)

Comment: @Paul Well done! That's what I had in mind.

Comment: Wow!  I had simply never heard of ```as.roman```.  Well done Paul.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, @KevinCruijssen!

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 246 bytes, [cracked by ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214064/3852)

```hs
infix 0#
0:p#x=p#1:x
1:p#x:z=p#x:x:z
2:p#x:y:z=p#(y+x):z
3:p#x:y:z=p#(y-x):z
4:p#x:y:z=p#(y*x):z
5:p#x:y:z=p#div y x:z
6:p#x:y:z=p#y:x:y:z
7:p#x:y:z=p#y:x:z
c:p#x|(q,_:r)<-span(<c)p=r#until((==0).head)(q#)x
_#x=x
main=readLn>>=print.(#[]).take 60
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc9LCoMwEAbgfU4hZJO0VWIfFoLxBL2BiAS1GLQhPlqi9O5pkpV2M/P/32JgWj51Td8bI@RT6IBAQKiCmikYUw1il@nK3LQbnH1fvKDlqLG1y85Cb9edHbzdNlaLT7AE7mKy0YX6BO5/toLKyRcNp5KOOA0nxSVKK6zYCN9yFj1CjBEctQ2vMRog1qC0P2jw4kKy0epDZhlTo5BzhGBe4GjmXRMkxJicFD8)

Input is taken over STDIN, and output is printed to STDOUT. The flag is the output string: `[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251,257,263,269,271,277,281,283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,409,419,421,431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,467,479,487,491,499]`

(Those are the primes from 2 to 499.)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214064/64121).

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 15 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214003/81203) by [w123](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98349/w123)

```
#//.a_:>Head@a&
```

(Edited to reduce byte count. Solution should be the same; all the unintended solutions I can think of should be trivial to adapt.)

Flag: `flag`.

Input by function argument, and output by return value. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78r6yvr5cYb2XnkZqY4pCoFv3/f6y@fkBRZl7JfwA)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214003/98349)

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 29 bytes, [cracked by pppery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213986/86301)

```r
function(x) intToUtf8(cos(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCr8D@tNC@5JDM/T6NCUyEzryQkP7QkzUIjOb8YKKD5P03DQPM/AA)

The flag to output is the string `"R"`.

---

The solution is `5.1i`.

Although \$\forall x\in\mathbb R, -1\leq\cos x\leq1\$, those bounds don't hold for complex \$x\$: \$\cos(a+ib)=\cos x\cosh y -i \sin x\sinh y\$, which is unbounded. We want to find \$x\$ such that \$ \cos x=82\$ (the ASCII codepoint of `R`); pppery gave the answer `x=5.0998292455...i`. The shorter `x=5.1i` works, because `intToUtf8` can take a complex argument and cast is as integer by ignoring the imaginary part, and rounding down the real part to an integer.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213986/46076)

Comment: @pppery Well done!

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213995/48931) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)

```
OÆTP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//cFtIwP///wE)

Outputs `160.58880817718872`.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I got to `160.5888081771887`...

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213995/78410)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage), [cracked by *@ovs*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214029/52210)

```
F}žhм9£.ER.V*
```

+5 bytes to close [a different crack found by *@ovs*](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/frVbPNUgvTOv/f0OugqLMvBKN1LwUW/WYPENjcxNjC0tTYxNzdc38InVDBSN1AA) (although he's free to post it as an actual crack instead if he chooses to).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/frfbovowLeywPLdZzDdIL0/r/PzEpGQA)

Expected output: `\n137438953472\n` (where the `\n` are of course newlines).

**Code explanation:**

```python
F              # Loop `N` in the range [0, input-1)
 }             # Close the loop
  žhм          # Remove all digits
     9£        # Only keep the first 9 characters
       .E      # Evaluate and execute as Python code
         R     # Reverse
          .V   # Evaluate and execute as 05AB1E (legacy) code
            *  # Multiply two values
               # (after which the result is output implicitly with a single trailing newline)
```

Tip 1: the program + intended solution only works in the legacy version of 05AB1E (built in Python 3) for two reasons. This won't work in the latest 05AB1E version (built in Elixir), where all these builtins as mentioned in the code explanation above will also act the same as *described*.
Tip 2: it won't time out on TIO, <s>so an input like `274359834731`, which would result in `137438953472\n` (note it's missing the intended leading newline) isn't the intended solution, since the loop takes too long</s> (no longer possible after the 5 bytes had been added). The intended solution runs in less than 0.2 seconds on TIO.
Tip 3: one of two reasons mentioned in tip 1 is a bug with `.E` and a certain type of input (which is ALSO in [*@ovs*' initial crack](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/frVbPNUgvTOv/f0OugqLMvBKN1LwUW/WYPENjcxNjC0tTYxNzdc38InVDBSN1AA)), that I abuse to get the intended result.
Tip 4: there are three loose inputs (separated with newline delimiter), and the first and third inputs are the same

Comment: Are the quote marks (`"`) part of the output?

Comment: I don't think [this](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/frVbPNUgvTOv/f0OugqLMvBKN1LwUW/WYPENjcxNjC0tTYxNzdc38InVDBSN1AA) is the intended solution?! You might want to close that loophole

Comment: @Sisyphus No, those are indeed not part of the output. I'll remove them.

Comment: @ovs Oh, that's another way to get the output, lol.. But indeed not the intended solution, albeit somewhat close in one aspect. If you want you can post it as a crack, I don't mind. I was expecting there would be more than one way to get the output apart from my intended solution. But if not, I've just edited my program to hopefully close that specific crack, and make it a bit harder to try a variation of that approach. I've also added a third tip.

Comment: @ovs I just found another completely different approach that also works with the current program, so maybe I should just delete this.. It's a bit too broad and easy to abuse I realize. :/ - If anyone finds a crack, feel free to post it even if you think it isn't the intended solution with the current 13-byter. I'll reveal the intended solution and another approach to abuse it I found just yet in that case.

Comment: Now [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214029/64121) for real. From the 4th tip I guess this is still not the intended solution.

Comment: I guess [this](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/frfbovowLeywPLdZzDdIL0/r/35iroCgzr0RDk8sYAA) was the intended solution?

Comment: @ovs Yep, that second is indeed the intended solution. Well done!

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 93 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214081) by [pppery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46076/pppery)

```python
from functools import*;lambda a,b,c:(d:=reduce)(lambda e,f:e[f],c,d(getattr,b,__import__(a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBBbsMgELz7FSv3AhHKIe2hcpUH9A1RZG1gsZEwIFha5fUppq3UQ2@7O6OZ2Ul3XmN4fk35YXPcwNagOUZfwG0pZobD8AQ30lgLwTsEIgMYfkFk4JWgMGZWULzTBDX1m46GgCMsxBCDv/djV3cxwKdrtpVBrxgWF5aOegoLrxBt3zZ0oasM9kwf6MU4jv9nPLx53G4GAdVN6UmY6ZzJVE1S/ACk7EQXe1VaGdESIXNu3Hn@FphngVLKR3O4nF6mqxyGlF1gYcWhW7uQKgu5c8TYF1gpU3vD@9YONFL1yL0bAwlL2ccCCFyTp/0lzEvdKHDZS/nbxajGhp2Ox@MovwA)

- Input is function arguments, output is function return value.
- Flag is the string `pxeger` (my username)

---

pppery didn't find my intended solution, and noone else has, but here it is:

The function

> takes a module name to import, a list of attributes, and a list of indeces, and looks up a value. It is best explained with an example:
>   `! f("spam_module", ["eggs", "ham"], [2, 3]) ! # ==> ! import spam_module ! spam_module.eggs.ham[2][3] !`

Given that:

> My username is `regexp` (as in Regular Expression), backwards, and `regexp` is quite a common variable name

So we need to:

1. > Find a use of the word `regexp` in the standard library
2. > Access it using Python's extensive runtime introspection API
3. > Reverse it

Specifically

> In the `csv` module there is a class called `Sniffer` which has a method called `_guess_quote_and_delimiter` which uses a variable called `regexp`.

Python lets you

> access that variable name as an element of the attribute `.__code__.co_varnames`. (I recommend looking into everything you can get from `__code__` - it's very interesting, albeit excessive)

Then

> `regexp` is the sixth variable name used there, so I lookup `csv.Sniffer._guess_quote_and_delimiter.__code__.co_varnames[5]`

Finally,

> reverse that by slicing it with `slice(None, None, -1)` (equivalent to `x[::-1]`)

So the whole solution is

> `f("csv",["Sniffer","_guess_quote_and_delimiter","__code__","co_varnames"],[5,slice(None,None,-1)])`

Comment: You can ask me for hints in the [Robbers' chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115404)!

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214081/46076)

Comment: Very clever challenge. It's almost a shame I spoiled it.

Answer (score 6):

## [dotcomma](https://github.com/Radvylf/dotcomma), 819 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213963/guess-my-password-robbers-thread/214535#214535) by [the default.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36445/the-default)

```
[[,.][[,.],[.[[,.][.].]],.[[.,]]].,][,.]
[,],[[,.][[.][[[.][.].,][,.][.].,][[.][.
][.].,].[[[,.][[].[],.][[[,][,.].,]].,][
[,][.]].][,.][[,][[[,.][[[[.][.].,][,][.
][,][,.].,]].,].[[[,.][[[,][,.].,]][[].[
],].,][[,]].][,.][[,.][[[[.]][.][[[.][[.
]][[[[.]][[.][.][.].,][,.].,][.][,.].,][
,.][[.]].,][,.][.].,][[.]][,.].,][,.].][
.].,]][[.]].,]].,][,],[[[,.][.[[[,.][[].
[.],].,].][[,.][,.][,.].,]].,]][[,.].[.[
[.][,.].][[[[.][.][.][.].,][,.].,],][[[,
.][[[[[[[[[,][,.].,][,.].,][,][,.][.][.]
[.].,][.].,][.].,],],][.][.][.][.][.].,]
.,][.][.].,][,][,][,][,][,][,][[,.][[,][
,][,]].,][,][,][,][[,.][[,][,][,][,][,]]
.,][,][[,.][[[,.][[,]].,]].,][,]],.[[[,.
][[[[.][.][.].,][,][,][,.][[].[,],].,]].
,][[[,.][[[[[[[,.][.].,][.][.].,],][.].,
][.].,],].,][.][.][.][.].,][,][,][,][[,.
][[[,.][[,][,][,]].,]].,]]][.][[.]][[.]]
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/dotcomma/?p=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)

The flag is `accepted`.

Since this language is quite new and I've only seen two people (the inventor and me) using it so far, I tried to find a good balance between too hard and too easy.

If I've done it correctly, the code will have two valid passwords. The interpreter is written in Javascript and therefore runs on your local machine.

On my notebook it takes about five seconds to show "accepted" after entering the correct password.

**Solution:**

The intended solution is the number [49375](https://radvylf.github.io/dotcomma/?p=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). I initially wanted to use the decimal value of 0xC0DE (49374), but got things messed up in my head and ended up one number too high. The comparison function works in a way that the input  and the solution are being decremented in a loop until one of them becomes zero. Then the other one must be 1 to be accepted. That means, 49376 is also a valid solution.

Other known solutions are [49375], [49376], [49375, -1] and [49376, -1]

The way this was meant to be cracked:

dotcomma is an esoteric language that is really hard to read, so I don't wanted anybody, to really "decompile" it and know exactly, what each command does, but to puzzle around with the blocks.

As already stated in my first comment, the language works a bit like Brain-Flak. The input will implicitly become the initial values in the queue and after the program ended, the content of the queue will implicitly be printed. So an empty program is a [cat program](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Cat_program).

To solve this, you first need to find the start and end of each block, what will result in something like this:

```
(1) [[,.][[,.],[.[[,.][.].]],.[[.,]]].,]
(2) [,.]
(3) [,],
(4) [[,.][[.][[[.][.].,][,.][.].,][[.][.][.].,].[[[,.][[].[],.][[[,][,.].,]].,][[,][.]].][,.][[,][[[,.][[[[.][.].,][,][.][,][,.].,]].,].[[[,.][[[,][,.].,]][[].[],].,][[,]].][,.][[,.][[[[.]][.][[[.][[.]][[[[.]][[.][.][.].,][,.].,][.][,.].,][,.][[.]].,][,.][.].,][[.]][,.].,][,.].][.].,]][[.]].,]].,]
(5) [,],
(6) [[[,.][.[[[,.][[].[.],].,].][[,.][,.][,.].,]].,]]
(7) [[,.].[.[[.][,.].][[[[.][.][.][.].,][,.].,],][[[,.][[[[[[[[[,][,.].,][,.].,][,][,.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.].,],],][.][.][.][.][.].,].,][.][.].,][,][,][,][,][,][,][[,.][[,][,][,]].,][,][,][,][[,.][[,][,][,][,][,]].,][,][[,.][[[,.][[,]].,]].,][,]],.[[[,.][[[[.][.][.].,][,][,][,.][[].[,],].,]].,][[[,.][[[[[[[,.][.].,][.][.].,],][.].,][.].,],].,][.][.][.][.].,][,][,][,][[,.][[[,.][[,][,][,]].,]].,]]]
(8) [.]
(9) [[.]]
(10) [[.]]
```

Then try out, what each block does.

Block 1 (filter): This block actually answers *the default.*'s question (sorry, I didn't answer it clearly. No other submission had to answer details about the password, and the "wrong password :(" was the only red herring I added to the program. So I didn't want to say "No, it's actually a five digit integer"). If you run that with different data types (numbers, strings, lists of numbers or strings), you will see that it returns the first element of a string or list, if it has multiple elements, or it will return a 1 and the element, if you enter a number or a string/list with only a single letter in it. The purpose of this becomes clear, if you add the second block to it.

Block 2 (delete first element): If you run blocks 1 and 2, you will see that the output will be empty if you input anything with multiple values. Only single numbers or single letters will remain in the queue. (Actually *the default.* found a bug in the programming language, because negative values should not be possible in the queue. You can't programmatically write a negative value onto the queue, and negative values won't be written to the output, but apparently they still can be read from input). So from this point, it should be clear that the password is either a number or a single letter.

Block 3 (run next block, if there's something in the queue): This will not change the output, but is there for control. You can ignore it.

Block 4 (build constants for comparison): This will build the list [49375, 96, input]. At this point, you may ask yourself, what the big number is for and that it may be important for the password.

Block 5 (run next block, if there's something in the queue): Same as block 3. Since there are three values in the queue, this will also rotate the queue, so the output is [96, input, 49375].

Block 6 (compare input and password): As stated earlier, this decrements the input and the number 49375, until one of them becomes zero. Then decrements the other another time and appends the 96 to it. The output is [49375-input (or input-49376), 96]. At this point, you should point out that you have to change the input in a way that the first value becomes something interesting, like 0, -1 or maybe 96?

Block 7 (write output): This block checks if the first value is 0. If so, it uses the second value to build the string "accepted". If not, it fills the queue with the string "rejected".

Blocks 8-10: Those are just fillers, so my submission will have a nice rectangle shape.

Comment: Is the password a string?

Comment: I think, it would become too easy if I told you details about the password. The format is one of the formats that are recommended by the interpreter website (a plain number or a string or a list containing only numbers or strings). A little hint: The language is a bit like Brain-Flak. At the start, the input is written into the queue and at the end, the queue is written to stdout. So you can run fragments of the code and find patterns in the output. The nesting level will help you

Comment: @thedefault. As far as I have read, dotcomma only supports integers.

Comment: @SunnyMoon: If you want to say "It doesn't support floating point number types", you're right. If you want to say "It doesn't support strings", you're wrong (the output "rejected" or "accepted" already is a string). Strings in the input are split into their characters and their codepoints are written into a queue of BigIntegers. If you enter an integer, it will become the only value in the queue of BigIntegers. Depending on the selected output type, it will either print the values of the queue or try to translate the values to their unicode codepoints and build a string from that.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214535)

Answer (score 5):

I'll get things started off with one that probably won't be extremely difficult but may take some thought.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 78 bytes: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213966/68942) by [wastl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78123/wastl)

```python
while 1:
	try:l=input()
	except:l=''
	exec(l,{},{"exit":0,"quit":0})
	print(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrLCsMgEADP8StkL1HwEOlN6MeUZKmC6FY3JCHk220et5lhaGOf06u1xYeI0jrRcdlcfIdEMystOlxHJD5L31@Co4pmP8wOuAYGNxj4zTcc50wlJFZWt/YQ0KfWJZdJfjNW6bEg6D8)

Flag is nothing. As in, . The program should not output anything.

Comment: [cracked](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/vzwjMydVwdCKi7OkqNIqxzYzr6C0REOTizO1Ijm1oAQooq4O4qQma@ToVNfqVCulVmSWKFkZ6CgVloIZtUDFBUWZeSUahpr//xclZhanKgRXFpek5roCVQIA)

Comment: @Noodle9 Not the solution I expected or would've figured out but very nice job! Unfortunately seems someone beat you to it on the robbers' thread side.

Comment: Oh, you already saw it. Was about to comment.

Comment: Another solution, with nothing to STDERR: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/vzwjMydVwdCKi7OkqNIqxzYzr6C0REOTizO1Ijm1oAQooq4O4qQma@ToVNfqVCulVmSWKFkZ6CgVloIZtUDFBUWZeSUahpoI8wwA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: I've just realised your intended solution was probably `break`

Comment: @pxeger `break` wouldn't work because `exec` doesn't get the context of being with a `while` loop. however, it would cause an error, which would prevent any output to STDOUT, which was an oversight on my part cuz you can just do anything that causes an error. I should've specified that STDOUT and STDERR should both be blank. My intended solution was actually `globals()['__builtins__']['exit']()`, though `del exit;exit()` works too.

Comment: You could actually just use `__builtins__` instead of `globals()['__builtins__']`. But, yes, your password can be anything that raises an error, like, for example, `!`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 85 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213963/guess-my-password-robbers-thread/213989#213989) by [r3mainer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11006/r3mainer)

```python
import re,time
b=input()[:40]
a=time.time()
re.match(b,b)
if time.time()-a>9:print(0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoVackMzeVK8k2M6@gtERDM9rKxCCWK9EWJKoHIjQ0uYpS9XITS5IzNJJ0kjS5MtMUkCR1E@0srQqKMvNKNAw0//8HAA)

Prints `0`. Works on TIO.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213989/11006)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is completely valid, since theoretically, I could have a computer which no 40-char regex could occupy for longer than 9 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [19 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213963/guess-my-password-robbers-thread/214178#214178) by [r3mainer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11006/r3mainer)

```
€weL˜ù┼óª˜›’U•žfcmº
```

<s>I would provide the unpacked form, but it's rather trivial to decode</s> adds to the challenge if you have to decode it yourself. Not terribly difficult, but it requires you to access the source code. The flag you want is:

```
7.9228162514264337593543950336e+28
```

this was done in the [online interpreter](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn). This shouldn't be too difficult, and multiple inputs should theoretically work. However, I encourage you to try and figure out the one I used (you will know immediately if you found the right one).

## Solution + Explanation

The flag r3mainer used was `J0e_Biden!`. The flag I intended to be the solution will remain hidden, as to encourage others to try :). However, to make it easier, here is an explanation for the program `:*:*((|:(|\):}):i0^:i"n`

```
:* Square
  :* Square
      ( Begin expression
        (
            |: Bifurcate*
              (
                |\ Fold with concatenation (remove spaces)
                  _ Variable initialized to STDIN; implied
              ) End expression
          :} Tail
        )
      :i Index of
        0 Literal zero
    ^ To the power of
        _ Implied
      :i
        "n" literal string
```

- Note: bifurcate is currently broken, and this program takes advantage of that. Basically, `|:(...):}` is a synonym for reversing the string `...` (don't you love bugs?)

Comment: This appears to be the unpacked code: `:*:*((|:(|\):}):i0^:i"n`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214178/11006)

Answer (score 4):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), 104 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213963/guess-my-password-robbers-thread/214030#214030) by [@thedefault](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36445/the-default)

```
*^(%  _+*^)%(0_+%)%  _+^$($_^_$_^_$+!!!!!!!!!+++++++++^$)+_^_  _+$(_^^^^^^^^^^_$^$)+xx_+$(_0+_$^$)+!!@@@
```

The flag to this program is `$$$` output to STDOUT.

I guarantee that the flag will appear in at least 5 seconds given the correct password.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYpBCoAgEEWvojCCNhuP4DXazCAqtIgSI@r2loY9@Iv/309hizl4v5Y11zqRVkIwTmSUtozK9EqggYl7UA5wQGDwVe0JmumHoZn77rPFr0rpnKt13s8isj@Oay9RLKkk@QA)

### What does it even do?

```
*^(%  _+*^)%(0_+%)%  _+^$($_^_$_^_$+!!!!!!!!!  # Push the password integer...
+++++++++^$)+_^_  _+$(_^^^^^^^^^^_$^$)+        # ...from STDIN onto the stack
xx_+$(_0+_$^$)+                                # Divide by the ASCII value of 0 i.e 48
!!@@@                                          # Print the result as a character thrice.
```

Therefore:

\$x = 48 · 36 = 1728\$

Where x is the password.

FYI 36 is the ASCII value of `$`.

Comment: [cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214030)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-n`), 33 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213963/guess-my-password-robbers-thread/213982#213982) by [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)

```perl
length()<28 && !/\w/ && eval eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8nNS@9JEND08bIQkFNTUFRP6ZcH8RILUvMARP////LLyjJzM8r/q@bBwA)

The flag is `Flag`. The input is stdin and output stdout.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213982/17602)

Comment: that was it, i thought it wouldn't be too difficult for a perl hacker :)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 23 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213998/44718) by [Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus)

```javascript
a=readline()
print(a+a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEtLshMSS3Kzc/LTq38/z/Rtig1MSUnMy9VQ5OroCgzr0QjUTtREygBAA)

- Expect output: `aaa`
- Input / Output use stdin, stdout

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213998/48931)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 85 bytes, [cracked twice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213963/guess-my-password-robbers-thread/214105#214105) by [the-default](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36445/the-default)

```ruby
x=gets
puts (x[0...n=x.size/2].to_i*x[n..-1].to_i).to_s(36) if x[-9..-1]=="123456789"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8I2PbWkmKugtKRYQaMi2kBPTy/PtkKvOLMqVd8oVq8kPz5TqyI6T09P1xDC0wSRxRrGZpoKmWkKFdG6lmA5W1slQyNjE1MzcwtLpf//LS3MzUxNjI0M4YIA)

Flag is: `codegolfguessmypasswordrobber001qtr5vxskd64lddb0gsyw2w4hp8zd1t0j`, as a string, in STDOUT.

### Explanation

Two prime numbers have been chosen, each having 50 decimal digits. One of them ends with "0123456789", and their product begins with `codegolfguessmypasswordrobber` when written in base 36.

```ruby
p = 91642145128772682907542781226248344977333099146327
q = 15416260853069873976599113800182718102190123456789
n = p*q = 1412779214440046356547554449820888121475969772090456386542605159205021769559275444371360154172564003
```

This looks like an [RSA factoring challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Factoring_Challenge), and factorizing the semi-prime is definitely one way to find the password. Bruteforce was explicitly forbidden for this challenge, though. And apparently, it wasn't too hard anyway to factorize n with an open-source program called [cado-nfs.](http://cado-nfs.gforge.inria.fr/) I should probably have picked a longer semiprime, e.g. [RSA-200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-200).

There's a (badly hidden) backdoor : [`String#to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#method-i-to_i) is happy to convert any string to an integer.

> Extraneous characters past the end of a valid number are ignored.

So `"1x000123456789".to_i` gets converted to `1`, and the challenge becomes trivial. It's now possible to "factorize" n as n*1.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214105)

Comment: Downvoter : constructive criticism is welcome. My post follows every rule above, and doesn't use any loophole.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, 32 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214107/92901) by @Sisyphus

<sup>Edit to reduce score by 1: `(p eval$_)` → `p(eval$_)`</sup>.

```ruby
!/[Scfpv\.:\?'"%<`(]/&&p(eval$_)
```

Input via STDIN. Flag is `"""\n` (three double-quote characters with trailing newline) printed to STDOUT.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214107/48931). I guess unintended.

Comment: @Sisyphus Indeed! Time for a rethink.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/), 84 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219217/64121)

Takes Python code as input from input from stdin. The code is only executed if it consists of a subset of the characters of `'\n ,.:;=@_abcdefijlmnoprstvz'` and the keyword `class` occurs at most two times.

```python
c=open(0).read()
{*c}<{*'\n ,.:;=@_abcdefijlmnoprstvz'}!=3>c.count('class')!=exec(c)
```

[Try it online! (on 3.7.4)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9k2vyA1T8NAU68oNTFFQ5OrWiu51qZaSz0mT0FHz8ra1iE@MSk5JTUtMysnNy@/oKi4pKxKvVbR1tguWS85vzSvREM9OSexuFhdU9E2tSI1WSNZ8///gqJMoISuoYGRqSYA)

The flag is `-1025` (printed to STDOUT).

My intended solution:

> ```python
> @print
> @int.__invert__
> @object.__sizeof__
> class o:__slots__=__name__,__name__,__name__,__name__
> ```
>
> [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dctBCoMwEIXhvaewq6iIFNzZpuQghSGOI1V0EpJUWsWzp7b7bh4/Hzz7Dg/DdYwojSXOznnlSHdZnmwF7tetEHdOy6q5SAW6xY76YZxmNtb5sKxiP8n6hhWaJ4dM4KS9F/lJ0oswwzxGZd3AIVHHVAADL@QCQKJMOxJ@yQ8rmf6g3zc1zUGTCR5AArCeCaD8Hx8)

Comment: Cracked: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219217/69850

Answer (score 4):

## Stable Rust 1.52.1, 171 bytes

```rust
fn u<T:'static>(_:T){use std::any::*;let _=unsafe{(1 as*mut T).read_volatile()};let a=type_name::<T>();print!("{}",&a[41..]=="(((), ()), ((), ()))>"&&a.contains("&dyn"))}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=42b77b899185325676337b94b5d4e470)

Entering the right password will print `true` and won't segfault (or print anything to stderr). This relies on implementation-defined behavior, so this will only probably work on different versions of Rust.

> Password: `u::<fn(&dyn std::any::Any)->(((),()),((),()))>`.

Explanation:

> There are probably other valid passwords but this is the intended one.
>  The function is generic over all `'static` types so you can put in
>  almost anything into the function. However, most types will immediately
>  segfault- `unsafe{(1 as*mut T).read_volatile()}` is a volatile read of
>  address `1`. However, not everything will segfault- in Rust, types with a
>  size of zero can be read from any well-aligned non-null pointer, and
>  most zero-sized types have an alignment of one.

> This brings me to the second safeguard: parsing the type name.
>  This is the implementation-defined part- the `type_name` function
>  is only guaranteed to be a best-effort description of the type.
>  The type name was chosen to be particularly difficult to find a
>  zero-sized type to match. The solution I have uses a particular
>  monomorphization of the function I submitted to pass the criteria.
>  It is likely possible to define another type that meets the criteria.
>  [Ungolfed code with solution entered.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5789fa4be23e9abef6b7d2cb30c8e39f)

Comment: You are already safe but we still have no ideas what the password is.

Comment: @nrgmsbki4spot1 oops I forgot about this. Solution and explanation added.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 26 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213963/guess-my-password-robbers-thread/235306#235306) by emanresu A

Seemed like a cool challenge, so here's an easy one.

Pass any JS value into the function. Flag is `true` printed to stdout. (boolean, not string.) If there is any other output apart from `true` is considered not cracked.

```javascript
x=>console.log({}[x][x]())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/wtYuOT@vOD8nVS8nP12juja6IhaINDQ1/6dpaP4HAA)

Intended solution:

> `{v: 0, toString() {Object.prototype.f = () => true; return this.v++ ? "f" : "valueOf"}}`

This works because:

> `{}[x]` calls the `toString` method of `x`

> `valueOf` returns the original object

> Therefore, modifying the Object prototype to add a method `f` in the `toString` method of `x`, returning `"valueOf"` the first time and `"f"` the second time does the trick

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213963/guess-my-password-robbers-thread/235306#235306)

Comment: Oh. I never even thought of modifying prototypes :p

Comment: @emanresuA My reasoning was that you got 3/4 of the way there (self modification using tostring) so reposting a patched submission is like reposting 1/4 of the original problem

Comment: No, I used `{}["constructor"]["is"]`, basically `Object.is`, which returns truthy when called with no arguments.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 31 bytes (safe)

```
I.dI:⅛kF*×u⅛Ė.SṪḢ42f÷₍+*Π¾J∑Cøṙ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=I.dI%3A%E2%85%9BkF*%C3%97u%E2%85%9B%C4%96.S%E1%B9%AA%E1%B8%A242f%C3%B7%E2%82%8D%2B*%CE%A0%C2%BEJ%E2%88%91C%C3%B8%E1%B9%99&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Flag: `EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE` Flag should be printed to STDOUT.

Under the original specifications for this cop, okie had a clever crack [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237565/101522), but that was an unintentional crack, so a couple clarifications are in order.

- The input will not contain any subset of the flag.
- The program should not return any errors.

> Intended Solution: `21⅛3` [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=I.dI%3A%E2%85%9BkF*%C3%97u%E2%85%9B%C4%96.S%E1%B9%AA%E1%B8%A242f%C3%B7%E2%82%8D%2B*%CE%A0%C2%BEJ%E2%88%91C%C3%B8%E1%B9%99&inputs=21%E2%85%9B3&header=&footer=)
> Before execution, Vyxal attempts to execute the input and see what it returns. The reason for this is to allow you to do things like input a list in Vyxal format, and it will work as intended. This also allows you to put Vyxal code in the input, but normally it will just get captured as a string. For example, and input of `69d:e` would just input the string `69d:e`.
> However, if you put a number at the end of that input, it only captures that number as input, and discards all of the code leading up to it. For example, an input of `69d:e2` would input the number `2`, and discard the `69d:e`.
> In the discarded code, trying to assign variables and functions doesn't do anything, nor does assigning to the global register, since those are in a different scope from the main program. However, the global array is global, and persists after the input execution. In the solution, `21⅛3` pushes `21` to the global array, then inputs `3`.
> Now let's go through the program step-by-step.
> `.dI:⅛` - Push 1 to the global array and to the stack
> `kF*` - Multiply `FizzBuzz` by the 1 on the stack
> `u⅛` - Push -1 to the global array
> `×  Ė` - Multiply the `FizzBuzz` by the inputted 3 to get `FizzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzBuzz`
> `.SṪḢ` - Push `.`
> `42f÷₍+*Π` - Push 48
> `¾J∑` - Concatenate the global array and the 48 and add. We used the input to push 21 to the global array, so this comes out to 69.
> `C` - Convert to character to get `E`
> `øṙ` - Regex replace: In string `FizzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzBuzz`, replace with `E` anything matching the regex `.`

Comment: Welp, time to learn Vyxal

Comment: I feel like the solution to this is to somehow get a function onto the stack to change the behavior of `øṙ` but I definitely don't understand Vyxal well enough to crack it

Comment: @Mayube That's a possibility. Who knows? Mayube, mayube not. :P

Comment: [here](https://gist.github.com/chunkybanana/e0a1fbf9a8b511fce3527c4be41ee855)'s a basic explanation.

Comment: can we have exception?

Comment: @AaroneousMiller [here's an attempt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237565/101762)

Comment: @okie Oh, that's clever! However, that's not the intended solution. I suppose I should specify that the the flag won't be in the input, and there won't be any errors.

Comment: @AaroneousMiller I think I will try to get another solution if I found some time to spare :P

Comment: the added `I` limit input to be not string

Comment: Does this still work in 2.6?

Comment: So the input isn't a string... that's useful. (`*` has different behaviour on str,str in 2.4 & 2.6)

Comment: @emanresuA Oh shoot, I messed up. I thought I tested it in 2.6, but I accidentally tested 2.4 instead. ***It does not work in 2.6.***

Comment: Ok. Btw the TIO isn't updated

Comment: I'm sure I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: does that mean it no longer works?

Comment: @okie It still works on the lyxal.pythonanywhere.com site, but not on the new vyxal.pythonanywhere.com site. Lyxal.pa is running Vyxal 2.4, whereas vyxal.pa is running 2.6. The TIO link in the post links to the correct site.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 57 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238169/87606) by Conor O'Brien

```js
alert("xx".split(new RegExp(p=prompt())).join``.length>2)
```

The flag is `true`.

https://xkcd.com/2217/

Comment: May I ask why this doesn't work as a function?

Comment: [TIO](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr4R00EP@og90jtBqqTVbF5Uy8O824@xj0xaR85AYd4h3oAu@1jgiZSlKETqxxywJ3m6CYywsxVLntfa1CKW0C0jGaA905FO19gM) in case anyone wants to try it out, although I don't know if it works without `alert` or `prompt`.

Comment: @rues If it was a function, someone could crack it with `(Array.prototype.join=()=>"aaaa","")`. (hence my earlier inquiry)

Comment: And yes, my intended crack works on that TIO (though the version in the answer is normative)

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238169/31957)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 117 bytes, [cracked by @tjjfvi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238394/)

```
_=>{c=prompt();if(/[^!-'*-Za-z]/.test(c))throw'CHEATER!';x=(o=>o(o.a,o.b,o.c,o.d))((0,eval)(c));return(x===x&&x!==x)}
```

The function must be called without arguments. The password must be provided via `prompt()`, and the *return value of the function* must be `true` (boolean). Otherwise logging `true` to the console **is not** acceptable. You may only use language features as specified in the ES6 standard, using platform-dependent APIs is forbidden.

You can test your passwords here:

```js
f=_=>{c=prompt();if(/[^!-'*-Za-z]/.test(c))throw'CHEATER!';x=(o=>o(o.a,o.b,o.c,o.d))((0,eval)(c));return(x===x&&x!==x)}

console.log(f())
```

I *really* hope I managed to filter out all passwords other than the intended one :D

Comment: Did you mean something like `x==x&&x!=x`?

Comment: @tjjfvi Nope. It's strict equality on purpose. And yes, it has a solution.

Comment: Are you sure? :P

Comment: @tjjfvi Yes, tried before posting (and now too). I *love* JavaScript because of such things. That's supposed to be a tough challenge, and looks like it's working. Good luck with it!

Comment: [Result of the intended password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MceM2.jpg)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238394/87606)

Comment: I forgot for a solid half-hour that I could make a function without needing parens with `x=>...` 

Comment: @tjjfvi Great solution, that was the intended one! Btw, I originally banned parentheses to avoid calls to `console.log`, but then I thought it would just be easier to require the *return value of a function* to be `true`, and left the restriction in place as a way to make the challenge harder.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/), 95 bytes, [cracked by wastl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213974)

```
import os;(c:=os.getenv("A")).isidentifier()and c not in"printinput"and eval(c)(os.getenv("B"))
```

Input is via environment variables. (no TIO link because it doesn't support them). Flag is `the_flag`.

@wastl did not find my intended solution - theirs was much simpler. Here is what I indended:

`PYTHONBREAKPOINT=builtins.print A=breakpoint B=the_flag python -c 'import os;(c:=os.getenv("A")).isidentifier()and c!="print"and eval(c)(os.getenv("B"))'`

The `PYTHONBREAKPOINT` environment variable describes a function to be called when you use `breakpoint()`. Python has a lot of weird implicit behaviours like this. I intentionally left "input is environment variables" vague so you would think it would only be `A` and `B`

Comment: Is output to *STDERR* fine?

Comment: Please include how `the_flag` will be outputted

Comment: (initially edited, but now I'm not sure if it's equivalent) does [this](https://tio.run/##VYwxDsIwDEX3nsLy5CxdWFBRB3oNxFClKVgCO0pMJU4fjIQErO//9/LTriq7fS6N71mLgdau09on2bionPCIZxgB8Q9OH/iVDhSH0S@XZP4i10LoufKSxHjlVCjMskAEUQMWzIV9kPwwfPO0zTeKgX4KkxdaewE) work as a test link for someone writing a solution?

Comment: cracked: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213974/78123

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 25 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213981/97730) by [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)

```javascript
y=s=>(l=s.length)?l:l/l|1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v9K22NZOI8e2WC8nNS@9JEPTPscqRz@nxvB/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGpYZSQWJxcXl@UYqSpuZ/AA)

The flag is `0`.
**Input**: function parameter.
**Output**: returned value of function.

Comment: By the way, I think you should say that it's an integer, otherwise you'd be leaving yourself vulnerable to cracks like [this](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v9K22NZOI8e2WC8nNS@9JEPTPscqRz@nxvB/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGpUY1RNpKQclAqVZT8z8A)

Comment: Actually that was the crack I had in mind. Suppose it wasn't as hard as I was thinking it would be.

Comment: Mind if I post my own answer on the robbers thread?

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 4 bytes

```
i10p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PQoOD/fwA)

The flag is `Something smells delicious...` printed to STDOUT, and takes input form STDIN.
Invalid keys may not always terminate the program.

Not a difficult one, but I like this feature.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214023/64121)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 10428 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214052/94032) by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121)

Because no one said there was a character limit :)

The flag is `cracked!` otherwise there is no output.

```js
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]])+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]]+(([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]])[(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]((!![]+[])[+[]])[([][(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]](([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[+[]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+![]+(![]+[+[]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]])()[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((![]+[+[]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]])+[])[+!+[]])+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]])())
```

Comment: I suppose it's too late to add a character limit now :/

Comment: So is this just jsf*ck?

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214052/64121).

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript](https://nodejs.org), 2465 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214195/31957) by [the default.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36445/the-default)

```javascript
X=([...O],S=[])=>{let M,F,a,b,R,n;M=F=0;while(O.length)eval(("?S.shift())#[a,b]!2);F=a==b;?a-b)#M++#?M)#%#M=0#M=%#R=%O=[]#n=%n!n);if(F)O=n.concat(O)".split`#`[O.shift()]||"").replace(/%/g,"S.pop();").replace(/\?/g,"S.push(").replace(/!/g,"=S.splice(-"));return R};const U=prompt().split``.map(e => e.charCodeAt()).join``.replace(/9/g,"").split("").map(e=>+e);R={s:20,m:0x80000000,a:1103515245,c:12345,get q(){return R.s=(R.a*R.s*+R.c)%R.m},i(v){return R.q/~-R.m*v|0},get b(){return R.i(2)},h([...a]){for(i=~-a.length;i>0;i--){j=R.i(i+1);[a[i],a[j]]=[a[j],a[i]]}return a}};R.s=U.reduce((p,c)=>p+c,0);class S{constructor(w,n=0){this.w=w;this.n=n;this.s={};this.c={}}N(T=this){return new S(T.w,T.n)}P(T=this){for(let i=0;i<T.w;i++)if(!T.c[i])T.A(i,T.n++);return T}M(s,t,T=this){let A=T.c[s],B=T.c[t];T.s[A]=T.s[A]||[];T.s[B]=T.s[B]||[];T.s[A].push(...T.s[B]);T.s[B].map(c=>{T.c[c]=A});delete T.s[B]}S(a,b,T=this){return T.c[a]==T.c[b]}A(c,s,T=this){T.c[c]=s+="";T.s[s]=T.s[s]||[];T.s[s].push(c)}*[Symbol.iterator](){yield*Object.entries(this.s)}Z(f=false,T=this){let C,b,c,v,N,r,g,l,m;C=[];b=[c=0];for(;c<~-T.w;c++){if(T.S(c,c+1)||(!f&&R.b)){C.push(b);b=[c+1]}else{T.M(c,c+1);b.push(c+1)}}C.push(b);v=[];N=T.N();if(!f){for(let[i,s]of T){let q=R.i(s.length-1);if(!q)q++;g=R.h(s).slice(0,q);v.push(...g);g.map(c=>N.A(c,i))}}r=[];C.map(c=>c.map((e,i,a)=>{l=i+1==a.length;m=!l*2;m|=1*(v.indexOf(e)!==-1);r.push(m)}));return[N.P(),r]}static F(w=10,h=10){let s=new S(w).P(),r,g=[[1]],i=0;for(;i<w;i++)g[0].push(1,1);for(let i=0;i<h;i++){[s,r]=s.Z(i===h-1);g.push(...I(r))}return g}};let I=(r, last=false)=>{let D=[1],E=[1];r.map(c=>{D.push(0,+((c&2)==0));E.push(+((c&1)==0),1)});return[D,E]};class B{constructor(w=10,h=10){this.m=S.F(w,h);this.r=0;this.G=true;this.f()}a(x=this.x,y=this.y){return this.m[y][x]}f(T=this){T.x=T.y=T.ey=1;while(T.a()!=0)T.x++;T.ex=this.m[0].length-1;while(T.a(T.ex)!=0)T.ex--}W(){return this.x==this.ex&&this.y==this.ey}d(r=this.r){return [[0,1],[-1,0],[0,-1],[1,0]][r]}L(){this.r++;this.r%=4}F(){let o=this.x,p=this.y,d=this.d();this.x+=d[0];this.y+=d[1];if(this.a()==1){this.x=o;this.y=p;this.G=false}if(this.W()){console.log("win");this.G=false}}M(r){r=this.r+r;r%=4;let m=-1,d=this.d(r),x=this.x,y=this.y;while(this.a(x,y)!=1){x+=d[0];y+=d[1];m++}return m}T(f){let ms=[1,3,0,2],v=f(ms.map(e=>this.M(e)));while(v&&this.G){this["KLFK"[v%4]].bind(this)();v>>=2}return this.G}R(f){let Y=999;while(this.G&&Y-->0)this.T(f)}}(new B()).R(a=>X(U,a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVaPb9o6EP5X@CEquzFewjbptdlRtd1aTRtlAqa3Lc/SQgiQigQap/wQeP9639lOaPtepZazfb777rvvTO/DdSijPFkV7Ww5iZ9W@TJdFTWoEVqDbg2XUSwlD/PZOugI/@kHkIBz3hdsCIGg0N0v4qLWYzcsZGM2YJnfgxtw/c08WcSkzxdxNivmNF6HC0IaF0Mu58m0IJQ2A7wg6h3q30AIMPYvwvaYNnuO07zo0War2QMXf1vNAbT6mKqZQSurZ9RPpuSG9iHj0TKLwoL0aYPL1SIpfjd/B/0qvjgcGg3K83i1CKOYvGm9mbHGkK@WK0L9lwf/XJQnj3JOXh7U9T4MTWxctxuU@nlcPOZZbaB8TC6L2newfBFaQvjN03BFYk1dzKN5mF8jqZe6Xn6/TDI8P8Y/0/Eb5UWiLXMVuk5M/QHs5XnHZem5u/3LtT8sPPc89@17733n3XsWnXudt/g5Q/ofCN1X0LgEMuDhKRqnzoBHtDXgqWIJWb/weXjzp43bp@uDq0yE8csICelQxeam0aGg@@kyJwn8aYdlN/2k6/pJu03396C9E8ejfhAGiWBhcC8EBPqD6Q2hyqihUr7G9h0JmDxi/WTFIpTPyomYS/1oEUpZG@4NrfljVGDKDcvApftinki@gY1vjAwya0jYK2tFaKk7MgK9OpaRxZvakIz4ho14RtW347muRms2QZUmH9DBTxyHoqrqIx4hZDrilyTRt3C76vhI9YhkBauC6ACXoC9Iwa6MUQh/xGVwKcB@HA6B3bmyO1fPO5fCyg35tSe0dDQSiHCodMBIwKWi/iTGZHHNOqgh0XP2n1q1dyjAwBgLdUkiJo8@ZSjpQKNh0kiLRz7jkSWeiKrTYLhLx8sFT4o4D7ENApWxS@LF5LQ/vo@jgsdZkSexJLYLVP0iU5iGCxm/IucaUUZsze5YzmZswVL/GofYH0MQgSt83QQ/@vCnrfmPkOg9NmDEh4g8QjUdDqQ@PTkZ8DGl@2sLbkzNbccTKsZsWFev9PbHJXy0lXp2X@uMd1jsHTHPRn167H6QMCmW09rIon0wOpalvtuedX@gD47jz/BsTiQOqnkHXPaAkY/9m1F/VnXtjmvmE4ogcp36ujqIjEFilrDQPJmAIwNwnKcU6ovTjp8ewDsla55kk3jbn5KY1gE0mNymS6k6vkHBHf9GKMuFkkVYJFHthmzAc9kc/9iaJNgR2FDryWYQBJ4QTAvf8J98sNqfBW4pAI9httcDMjcu@0BiLpD8F74EAIai2ZGEzyTHoksxznDS9fXPQHJWw7kurDyq74qPgCjYJ/0XC6sE/9EGc5lDSHTSoYCjT/1PdtfseWYPAaojBx/ZJ6HKt@Pq9dvxzIXRaYoPOTLE5tS@GTnWZoxbwCuxtaeEqpBsjYr5lu2ssTuOmY0U7ESwFWpKngdsixrb4W@8A6/85hvxkGD7XHxNtigiPCvjpprsSmcvnLVHeSHettvqb/I67xbs/Xh7cmJxVRs7NSG5tfPjnSBwGdIctD3m4ofL2nqlFyJA0XwlJTE5grNGC96pG2K1s6w4WJUcsIk1JqQkcOvABCuxi51eYDtxaMwaSwfwygxbWJZesKo4N4JQlTuWSk33louYL5Yz0tgkWYO@dsYHWFdX1unkvgZshJbijDzjyyn7XwdLmktsuI9EI7yqhgp@6jiViFM1IlPLRSpRquwtc1lHsDVMSSqrb2oTsIdzilK1KdZlc25t8UHjy9ebL41g3XonBB/jYBsQFFlcd7vQUS87fKsGVc6fcHZ29hL17cnJz3a761Kz0tiUInq@r/S/FgMSQvcH@Y6vC316eurtPmerx6L@Lw) **The flag is `win`**. There should be no other output produced by the program. Although I designed this program to work with Firefox's implementation of JavaScript, it also works on node, hence the link. Input is a string through `prompt`, which is substituted for a command line argument in the header of the node TIO link.

There is very much method in this madness; brute force is neither recommended nor viable, hopefully. Slightly golfed. More so an attempt to make it to 2 weeks, than doing it with the lowest score possible—a proof of concept, if you will.

### Or, try it here, in your browser

```js
X=([...O],S=[])=>{let M,F,a,b,R,n;M=F=0;while(O.length)eval(("?S.shift())#[a,b]!2);F=a==b;?a-b)#M++#?M)#%#M=0#M=%#R=%O=[]#n=%n!n);if(F)O=n.concat(O)".split`#`[O.shift()]||"").replace(/%/g,"S.pop();").replace(/\?/g,"S.push(").replace(/!/g,"=S.splice(-"));return R};const U=prompt().split``.map(e => e.charCodeAt()).join``.replace(/9/g,"").split("").map(e=>+e);R={s:20,m:0x80000000,a:1103515245,c:12345,get q(){return R.s=(R.a*R.s*+R.c)%R.m},i(v){return R.q/~-R.m*v|0},get b(){return R.i(2)},h([...a]){for(i=~-a.length;i>0;i--){j=R.i(i+1);[a[i],a[j]]=[a[j],a[i]]}return a}};R.s=U.reduce((p,c)=>p+c,0);class S{constructor(w,n=0){this.w=w;this.n=n;this.s={};this.c={}}N(T=this){return new S(T.w,T.n)}P(T=this){for(let i=0;i<T.w;i++)if(!T.c[i])T.A(i,T.n++);return T}M(s,t,T=this){let A=T.c[s],B=T.c[t];T.s[A]=T.s[A]||[];T.s[B]=T.s[B]||[];T.s[A].push(...T.s[B]);T.s[B].map(c=>{T.c[c]=A});delete T.s[B]}S(a,b,T=this){return T.c[a]==T.c[b]}A(c,s,T=this){T.c[c]=s+="";T.s[s]=T.s[s]||[];T.s[s].push(c)}*[Symbol.iterator](){yield*Object.entries(this.s)}Z(f=false,T=this){let C,b,c,v,N,r,g,l,m;C=[];b=[c=0];for(;c<~-T.w;c++){if(T.S(c,c+1)||(!f&&R.b)){C.push(b);b=[c+1]}else{T.M(c,c+1);b.push(c+1)}}C.push(b);v=[];N=T.N();if(!f){for(let[i,s]of T){let q=R.i(s.length-1);if(!q)q++;g=R.h(s).slice(0,q);v.push(...g);g.map(c=>N.A(c,i))}}r=[];C.map(c=>c.map((e,i,a)=>{l=i+1==a.length;m=!l*2;m|=1*(v.indexOf(e)!==-1);r.push(m)}));return[N.P(),r]}static F(w=10,h=10){let s=new S(w).P(),r,g=[[1]],i=0;for(;i<w;i++)g[0].push(1,1);for(let i=0;i<h;i++){[s,r]=s.Z(i===h-1);g.push(...I(r))}return g}};let I=(r, last=false)=>{let D=[1],E=[1];r.map(c=>{D.push(0,+((c&2)==0));E.push(+((c&1)==0),1)});return[D,E]};class B{constructor(w=10,h=10){this.m=S.F(w,h);this.r=0;this.G=true;this.f()}a(x=this.x,y=this.y){return this.m[y][x]}f(T=this){T.x=T.y=T.ey=1;while(T.a()!=0)T.x++;T.ex=this.m[0].length-1;while(T.a(T.ex)!=0)T.ex--}W(){return this.x==this.ex&&this.y==this.ey}d(r=this.r){return [[0,1],[-1,0],[0,-1],[1,0]][r]}L(){this.r++;this.r%=4}F(){let o=this.x,p=this.y,d=this.d();this.x+=d[0];this.y+=d[1];if(this.a()==1){this.x=o;this.y=p;this.G=false}if(this.W()){console.log("win");this.G=false}}M(r){r=this.r+r;r%=4;let m=-1,d=this.d(r),x=this.x,y=this.y;while(this.a(x,y)!=1){x+=d[0];y+=d[1];m++}return m}T(f){let ms=[1,3,0,2],v=f(ms.map(e=>this.M(e)));while(v&&this.G){this["KLFK"[v%4]].bind(this)();v>>=2}return this.G}R(f){let Y=999;while(this.G&&Y-->0)this.T(f)}}(new B()).R(a=>X(U,a))
```

### Intended solution

the default.'s solution was very close to being exactly the same as mine, and in fact, conceptually equal to mine. However, mine has a bit tighter encoding:

> `Z5[_\\#\]:#][4\]!!!!\]\\\\ \\\]:(Z5[_\\#\]:#][4\]  \\\]4\\\]:4\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\%`

I'll probably released a half-golfed, half-annotated version of the source later.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214195)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 70 bytes, [cracked by @ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231473)

```
c=compile(c:=open(0,"rb").read(),"","exec").replace(co_code=c)
exec(c)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5NCsIwEIX3PUWYVQKxuBQhV_AKIU4nJFAzIZ1CPYubbvRO3sb6t33v8b3v9qhXSVzW9T5L3B2eMzrkS80jaTw6rlT03kI7g-kbhUEbC2CBFsJPUseA25I98kAOTRemiZrAiUVFbkoSqRhyEcVRJQpblYvC3vuB0fvuDdJovuc_h7_LCw)

Works in CPython 3.9.6. Takes input from STDIN and should output `42` with a trailing newline to STDOUT.

---

The challenge was to create something of a polyglot between Python source code and CPython bytecode. The Python source would be compiled (so it needed to be syntactically valid), and then have its bytecode replaced with itself, keeping constants and names.

My solution was:

```
d,F,d,S,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,44,43,42
```

Disassembly:

```
Bytes  Instruction      Argument  Meaning
d,     LOAD_CONST             44  stored integer 42
F,     PRINT_EXPR             44  ignored
d,     LOAD_CONST             44  stored integer 42
S,     RETURN_VALUE           44  ignored
...    [garbage...]
```

The list of numbers is just to get the Python compiler to store enough constants for `,` (decimal codepoint 44) to be a valid argument in order to index into the tuple and load `42`.

By the way, `PRINT_EXPR` is an opcode used solely by the Python shell to print the return value of an expression. It's never used in normal code, but it's very useful for hacking around in bytecode-land.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231473/64121)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 67 bytes, cracked [by @rak1507](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58644070#58644070) [and @ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231510)

```
def f():
 try:exec(open(0).read())
 except:0
 return lambda:["wow"]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3nVNS0xTSNDStuBRKiiqtUitSkzXyC1LzNAw09YpSE1M0NDW5FFIrklMLSqwMuBSKUktKi_IUchJzk1ISraKVyvPLlWIhRq0vKMrMK9EAmqWhGW0QqwkRhVkEAA)

Works in CPython 3.9.6. Input via stdin, and outputs by returning a [function that returns](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11317) a [singleton list](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11884). Your crack should change the output to the string `hah` (also in a singleton list, in a function, as the return value).

Addendum: I keep trying to write answers to [It almost works](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/231321), but I keep finding unintended workarounds and having to post them here where I can set stricter rules.

---

@rak1507 and @ovs both cracked this, presumably separately, using ctypes to directly mutate the strings. Here's my intended solution:

```python
import sys
def t(_, m, v):
    import sys
    if m == "return": v[0] = "hah"
    return sys.t
sys.t = t
sys.settrace(t)
```

If it weren't for some complicated problems (see below), I could have this answer which is a bit easier to read:

```python
import sys
def t(_, m, v):
    if m == "return": v[0] = "hah"
    return t
sys.settrace(t)
```

`sys.settrace` enables tracing for the interpreter, which means many operations trigger the calling of the given trace function (here that's `t`), a feature intended for implementing Python debuggers.

One of the operations that triggers a trace is just before the return of a function; the third argument is the returned object. In this case the returned object is a list which we can mutate, so when the second argument ("event type" is `"return"`), I set its first element to `hah`. (The first argument is the stack frame object, which is unused here).

My answer had to return a function that returns the value because tracing is not enabled until a new stack frame is entered (another function being called).

The trace function should return a new trace function (normally itself), or `None` to disable tracing. My trace function needs to return itself here, but because the code is run by `exec`, by the time the trace function is executed, it's lost a reference to its global scope and `t` is no longer defined. For this reason we need to store it somewhere else that won't be garbage collected. Here I chose to set it as an attribute on the `sys` module because it's convenient.

Comment: This is so much simpler than the other one, yet so much more confusing...

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231510/64121), but I assume you had something a bit more involved in mind?

Comment: It was rak1507, not me

Comment: @Ausername oops I'm stupid lol

Comment: [cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231536/100563)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 166 bytes, [cracked by @ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233208)

```
def f(s,a):1/(not{*"_.}"}&{*s});c=compile(s,"","exec");x=bytearray(c.co_code);[0for i in a for x[i]in[9]];return eval(c.replace(co_code=bytes(x)),{"__builtins__":{}})
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZBBasMwEEWvMmhRpKAqTbtpYnKNbowRijJOBI5kRnKwMTpJN9k0d-ptqhZn0d3Af-_zmc97P6Vz8Lfb15Da5_fv-xFbaHmURuw2a-5DmldMq8zy07yKWVR2b8Oldx0WhjHJcETLRDXuD1NCQ2QmbpUN2oYjiqp-aQOBA-fBwO851q5xvt42TUWYBvKAV9MVhbDvjEW-qH91kY9CyJlpfRhcl5yPWrPdnLNY1n705HzixSXeclYApAQxXBBiKtEJzkjIJNQbCa8S3iT8g4qMJ6T4wJRSjRBL--MnPw)

Works on CPython 3.9.6. Accepts two inputs: a string `s` and a list of integers `a`. Should return the dictionary `{"a": "b"}` (not a string that looks like that dictionary!).

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233208/64121)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 66 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214041/94032) by [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792)

```js
if (readline() === ([0][1]+"").slice(4,8)) console.log('cracked!')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQq1ibZuhDQYs2nkRayDjFlGloBJ3e3jvsazMluZ8@3@I4XTGc/JUim4LE1nkJDKi01grMuJppbesah@yFGOZuQVQUQ46eBx93aChZOtlVDZbyAw)

The flag is the string `cracked!`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214041/95792)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214080/64121) by [pppery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46076/pppery)

Just a single line of Python.

```python
eval(input(),{'__builtins__':{}})(**{0:0})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7UsMUcjM6@gtERDU6daPT4@qTQzpyQzrzg@Xt2qurZWU0NLq9rAyqBWE6i2IhOoCgA)

The password is inputted via STDIN, the flag is  (nothing) and should be printed to STDERR. That means no output to STDERR.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214080/46076)

Comment: @pppery Thats not how I intended it ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 73 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214083/64121) by [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger)

Hopefully this time there are no loopholes.

```python
s=input()
assert not{*s}&{*'()[]{}'}
eval(s,{'__builtins__':{}})(**{0:0})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExCoAwDADA3Vc42TQ4VN0EXyISKggWpIqJgoS8vd5dn@xnHkrhKeXrEfBVZN5uqfMpimyNogM/L2rOqu2NB3Crjmh90iEpM5Eb1cwDooYxmC@l64cf)

Just as [before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214079/64121), the password is inputted via STDIN, the flag is  (nothing) and should be printed to STDERR. That means no output to STDERR.

Comment: [not allowed, but the `-O` flag bypasses the `assert`](https://tio.run/##TY3NCgIhFIX38xThIn@YwmoTAz1DDzDIRUNIGFTmahDiq2c2q3bfOR@cE9/pGfylNbw5H3NifNCIdk07H1IRWPdFUMZnVSqtg33pheFYKIDJbknOIwCdSq2cCVHkJCtv7V8eAR5LX9zIaLSdZql6wGw282v6wel8VYyQkRDO@CfE5ILHdrh/AQ)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214083)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 113 bytes, [cracked by tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214165)

```javascript
f=n=>n!=42?`${n} is a number`:`${n} is the answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYnNCsIwDIBfJYKHDdTD2EGE6qs0znSLdKm2aUXEZ69Dwdv3c8WCaYh8023Z1@qMmKOsTN@d7Polb@AECJLnM0V7@CedCFDSgyJo@Fr2yjMqwT1TUg4CwYFnR5vfFi4U02IoF6CFnzqxjLYOQVLwtPNhbFzTd21bPw)

`f` needs to return `42 is a number`.

Probably an easy one, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Maybe not what you want, but it should work: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214165/44718

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 143 bytes, [cracked by Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214233/86301)

```r
function(x, y, z){
  if(length(ls(1)) > 1 | length(ls()) != 3) return("S")
  LETTERS[lengths(lapply(y, intToUtf8(x), z)) * lengths(lapply(y, intToUtf8(x+32), z))]
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCr8D@tNC@5JDM/T6NCp1KnSrM6M00jJzUvvSRDI6dYw1BT086wBsHX1FS0NdYsSi0pLcrTUApW0rT2cQ0JcQ0KjoaoKdbISSwoyKnUqNTJzCsJyQ8tSbPQqNAEmquphU@FtrERWFFs7f//AA)

[Once](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213985/86301) [again](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214055/86301), the value to output is the string `"R"`. The line with `length(ls())` is there to try to close some loopholes; in any case, you need to find objects `x`, `y` and `z` such that `f(x, y, z) == "R"` is `TRUE`.

---

Giuseppe [found](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214233/86301) a nice solution using the functions `^` and `~`. The solution I had in mind was `f(67, list(as.factor(1:3)), 4:6)`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcy9CsIwFEDhV4md7tUgxEiVSt26Odk6iUMpTQ2EtCS30Pjz7FF0cHM88HFcVCxnUY22Id1bmHjgN7xrBaa1HV3BeBCIe/H4NeIsl@haGp2FpExwdyiqqjiW56/xYOphMAEC15aq/kRqCxO@vzj/JxZy9UGXZ1SQbjgz2hPUfqnqhnoHIpOInK2zFOML) (any vectors of length 3 would work). The trick is that the functions `c` and `C` both exist (with the second being much less known). Calling `c(1:3, 4:6)` returns the length 6 integer vector `1 2 3 4 5 6`; calling `C(as.factor(1:3), 4:6)` returns a length 3 factor `1 2 3` (with contrasts `4 5 6`). The product of the lengths is thus 18, which is the position of `R` in the alphabet.

Comment: [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214233/67312) I went down a real rabbit hole with `C` and `D`, but figured it out in the end!

Comment: @Giuseppe Well done! I actually had a different solution in mind, with `c` and `C`.

Answer (score 2):

## [BrainF***](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 22 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213963/guess-my-password-robbers-thread/218948#218948) by [Cinaski](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72733/cinaski)

```
+++++[>,[--->+<]>.<<-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwSi7XSidXV17bRtYu30bGx0Y///DygtUShILC4uzy9KUchILUoFAA)

The flag is `wEe0H` with nothing else. This shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I made sure the flag would allow for a valid password

Comment: Wait i'm unsure did you forget to remove the password from the try it online link?

Comment: Maybe? I didn't look into that.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218948/72733)

Comment: @SuperPizz You did leave the password in, but I edited in a link without it and anyway, Cinaski has cracked your answer. Btw, you should add "Cracked" to the header of your answer, with a link to the robber answer, so people know it's cracked.

Comment: @Cinaski The script was pretty much like mine!

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 958 bytes, safe

```
x=[(9,23),(10,24),(10,25),(11,23),(11,24)]
def f(g):
    h=g.copy()
    for move in range(30):
        n=[]
        for i in range(12):
            n.append([])
            for j in range(36):
                c=0
                for (a,b)in[(-1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1),(0,-1),(0,1),(1,-1),(1,0),(1,1)]:
                    if i+a>=0 and i+a<12 and j+b>=0 and j+b<36:
                        c+=h[i+a][j+b]
                if h[i][j]==0 and c==3:
                    n[i].append(1)
                elif h[i][j]==0:
                    n[i].append(0)
                elif h[i][j]==1 and c!=2 and c!=3:
                    n[i].append(0)
                elif h[i][j]==1:
                    n[i].append(1)
        h=n.copy()
    for i in range(12):
        for j in range(36):
            if g[i][j]!=h[i][j]:
                if not((i,j)in x):
                    print('N')
    for (i,j)in x:
        if g[i][j]==h[i][j]:
            print('N')
    print('Y')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVPLboMwELzzFc4ptiCRDW2kRtl@Qu8V8oHwNGoNQqhKvp7aYEICrlCk7mVfs7MDLPW1LSoZdN0FQvzm@QHxMKOe/2L8q/bM1JmucydJM5ThnBwdpKyAfB9X9RWTPs2qBn1XPykSEjWRzFMcUIPUJiHkt0RjxQRk/h2wB@@juk5lgkNOHhp6sLzbcJgNaouBLmp6DkfemQgZ4h3zdkw9lvJ0cDqjQ5H2iUEMAN3nyz3aRIaEG70DRZFMdHhifh@W7nmsqvAUHOzzvV4XilCN8lAhuWNZodqqycEQxgCBnU4q4PjqGFlA0q8HsnUOusbBBkEb8Mcg@A/Wp56uADm/w79ua@18lIh8ELEBo@Zo@yCyajEWXqnOCV2IXW3dCNni7cd2knUbmSamjWDfOKMx6adKM/13dN0v)
Flag: `Y`. The password is taken through input to `f`, so to run the code just edit the last line `f([])`.

Solution:

> The code simply runs Conway's game of life on a finite grid, and tests whether the result after `30` ticks is the original grid with a particular set of `5` cells toggled. The solution is:

> Gosper's glider gun. `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VLLbsIwELzzFeaELQzyJi1SEe4n9F5ZPgTIw6h1IoQq@PrUTgLhkTSJZC5dWfLuenZmbW92OiSp9vP8yAV@o55PKAZGvZdqf7U7VHmweTnahhGKcEyWI2Qs4fF8k2YnTIowSvfoO/0JkdJoH@g4xD6rkNY0F/ISWKyqgeBdAQvwPMiyUG@xkOTmwBburhQWd4XWNpw95GwdDuiaKC3wDOgMzLXMzsrNRqxMsiKoECXAnstHHWsqQmoavHOGAr217gq8wt1N1@escVf@orm@6HfKE2FKpTBIOWqQMMfmUPKKcMO530ynDfD8dEAeIOHXDVk3B@vigLKhMffOju@CddDtEq7v57BttrrGxzQRl02MedXNsulDdHrAWNGdGSd0JM3dZnulD3jyManbupTUFbUib1a8o6nCTxNGWAhGkZMFnRhJkXCl404NWsigj8gF2UsN2p9ruNrfFdAlDv3ffJgatCi4@zfoPXuOpgQGUT5xJp@j5mb9azVJ8vwX)

Comment: There's no need to post the solution right now, you can do that after your answer is cracked or it's safe

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 202 bytes, Safe

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (h z)
  (when (procedure? z) (error "you lose"))
  (define a (λ (x) (not x)))
  ((λ (f) (call/cc (λ (k) (k (or (a z) (set! a ((eval f) k))))))) z)
  (and z (print (a "hello"))))
```

The flag is `hello`. The password (in the form of a quote-string) is passed as the argument to the `h` function.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LEcIwDETvqWIxF/lECdSicRSSscdmHAdCWqMHWjL@RDc9Pe1sZGMl5Xx17B@IbRsGGmVavIBmHHoA6D2LBz1jMDJuUe4FgyTGEKE@YYMLqyjd1POVQb8vaC@eDwm77tcGpwINO3czplu2AAsqacQtepV0qREkL3YovtV9zj7sRxy10OJT/VGzOBdUNXL@Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 322 bytes, safe

```python
from ast import*
a=input()
b=walk(parse(a,"","eval"))
c=Constant
n=Name
if not {z.__class__ for z in b}-{Load,Call,Expression,c,n}:
 for x in b:
  if (i:=instanceof)(x,c):
   if not i(x.value, str):
    break
  if i(x,n):
   if x.id=="getattr":
    break
 else:
  print(eval(a,{"__builtins__":{},"getattr":getattr})==eval)
```

Could probably be golfed more, but I'm trying to avoid accidentally leaking anything :P

Output is `True` followed by a newline

Solution:

> The program only runs programs that load names or constants and call functions. It also runs the input with only the global function `getattr` (which is essentially a function implementation of the `.`, so `a.b == getattr(a,"b")`, so our goal is to get to `eval` with only these pieces. The solution that I came up with was by building up from an expression that I came up with that could become eval using the classes that Python loads at runtime, and then slowly using pythons magic dunder methods to try to "simplify" down language features that I can't use to get to `getattr(getattr(getattr(getattr(getattr(getattr(getattr(getattr(getattr(getattr,"__class__"),"mro")(),"__getitem__")(1),"__subclasses__")(),"__getitem__")(getattr(getattr(getattr(getattr(getattr(getattr(getattr(getattr,"__class__"),"mro")(),"__getitem__")(1),"__subclasses__")(),"__repr__")(),"split")(","),"index")(" <class 'codecs.Codec'>")),"decode"),"__globals__"),"__getitem__")("__builtins__"),"__getitem__")("eval")`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU9BbsMgELzzihUnqKgvvVSWOEW9Vf0CWju4RcGAYN04sfx2FydRq952d2Z2ZtKFvmJ4eU1524YcR8BC4MYUM8ETQ@1CmkhI1ukz@pNImIsVqDhX3H6j51KyXh9iKISBWNAfOFrmBgiRYLk2xvQeSzEGhpjhCi5Atz4v7xGP6oDeq7c5ZVuKi0H1KqwtuxHnG7EuUF8J19YYu0Fv4yDFrHq5Q/CwcWJuapTJKiiU7xB02eLprq@4Cr@KuXFHrfmnJSTK/B/b@mL3Q8oukNj71aoLN6abnKeawRjeLqv6Uz@GVWq90@W2/QA)

Comment: `instanceof` isn't a thing in Python. Did you mean `isinstance`?

Comment: @pxeger I had actually meant to use isinstance, but I didn't realize until way too late to change it, and it would've changed the restrictions which would be unfair.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem) ([lazypxem.posixism.tio.sh (8e9ac7ceb2)](https://github.com/GH-TpaeFawzen/pxem.posixism/blob/8e9ac7ceb2f238d7066c5d065fbaf0d024505515/lazypxem.min.posixism)), filename only: 109 bytes, <s>safe</s> safe.

Sorry for misreading the rules; I misread I would safe if nobody cracked mine for one week; I had to wait for two weeks to be safe.

Some are escaped:

```
\002.r.w.i._._.-.-\240.z.d.aY.o.d.a\002.r.w.i.i.i.i.s.s.s.s._.i.!Q##.!.-.+.w.d.aY.o.d.a.w.+.i.c\001.+.a.+\377\377].+.+.z.d.aY.o
```

- Flag: `Y`, without trailing LF.
- Input from stdin, as a string consists of ASCII printables except space: 33 (!) to 126 (~).
- Output to stdout.
- This program works randomly; your password must always work.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVhtV@K6Fv4@vyLUShPb0gZBkVqVQa/DOcqo47hUQFehRcFSOG1RtHD@@tydtAiUubOuLGny7NfslzThJXj@tbFRcvaszm7Haee7@e2Svavv7HSKtr5T7Latrm7r@UJRLxZp8UvghEh1xsZ4YAUvSNfzecOZjIZ@iM6qj5WzM7Nq4PB95KAnJ@wMvW42y2ed4WBgeTY50GznVfPGrovyB1mazSbCF5Xrb6Yg4oQPqaO5Ak4iYsQecnkWD9SZMDf7s167ffxxfWzmdX17Dl58/1G7Pbt7rH6/ujqpXpvUaCBBjL5Wfnx7vDm5@lH7Xi/L7zMBmegdtbJZvqohGg2D3iSeyV9jkfv/IeEMxq4VOih45vzDUQjDt6FvByO3F2azltuzAqQ@IUmMqCyIR8JMMiX2lLLZ@s@zs@r5sVnmNjCzZxvBc68bGnyMGF8COJ3nIRI3CLNMmeUMGMoPXfsgC6F/tVwkZFDXcgNHmE6XaVw1l55MA8dGUqBNtHfNCODrQ5O4wg/UYkKcC3jmoh1M8BCSUPGQ@hqO6TT0kVoNULOhq3stJDWa3lZLmj75zgjlYuXaQ2FH1KJyxRDbRt3Qmh6fX4C5h1yu6Wma0a4Ys3jaeGB6KM2L2kgzwmWwpK9jlFJRG6bA3b11jFKQ9tKMpXWM6kVR66UZt9exPeB7TGNguZPCdnbXMUpBOEivb3sdoxRcfE0z7qxjVIeIddNu6@sY1SFiTtrHvXWM0oKo@WnT@XWMUpB@SzPurmM0D/5M0oyldYzmwcf3NOPeOkbz4M9HOgn6bzBwx0ovuriOUQqxDdOWC@sY1cGdQTreu@sY1cEdO226tI4VIP1yGgMX1RS2DXyZNAZei2kMnNlk2Eya4o6VbBc2SZqS96sWnbKmnBg29N8pk27iXJM0cdNj37mtJhG15nYz36QacAVabgu6dbLa32XXEDOR1nibvH9YdkvLRHWj7YLCmfEOza4hzdAaDwmVlbioIVtb0aF6SErMNx6OlBbYBQ9wIx6CC/kjxFx4TnhiHOW2gMQ9i63DekbcTVFTGNoGFyDFEcwyUQCjijYy2peAxmzKESj4ZLQ/GW3teM64wjanJHEo@4YYxeaOEFMNWxznRpU5ElZ4aMVMHShNr4HUj9aWzbSF/hICS@LxacWL1TjJArYRz2m8OCuWmoG35ctPlTnuW3iZ2nOTeHyDyBxXIC6TJLk8sou4xfE5TTTx/9iV2JMk678TlND81bGUEK3Xxa7VdlzTFJpUIBFfCW6Mhl7vsRO8dh0/HMgZcVNtMe4mxcTQnmIeVo/NiCrNGSNd4CZNaNayS8G4jQWWEEFh0ocwFsrCkaBws2SWGFzl/xPzsai1fcd64RPIWwUL7nA4Qt4wRAMr7Dz3vCcBWKX5cmVMtDamhPum8omazDJ8pscTESb/zCebfMLYoBl5I0rdoZ/ECjwyDBJJxmeXSjOJkF//qVfOT0ypCUepnJ97y/Vyj/BRc2ozX9BzHzk7Z93lhuyxxBJ/guTzCOPM5cZGLgNyMjAsZGAiA7UDshRGVk5ubu/usv8WTOVP/dKX6vf69Un92pSkL3jk97ywC@cH7pyYkITpWwepHQInhF@B3zGlryentXoE1SAHjmOTwIeTG@bDWXfsdcLe0EMX@JhEPxovyt@YtMxjA4YtWV7QTzCJfCcc@x7KyMCzoPy1oAB@QBeUvxcUpm5BuF4hMJMqXSLf4isSXZnAxd1QVSNhvlrwjHGVRHz9qLpAT/GVcv@pG06mbs9zDvRDUS@rS459iw2I1OAV@cDLXYbCFASyAqEYWjf/k5kfe@aS7Qo@n3t0PhWgeiD@7PTbC9GS6REs/e255zo4AyElw@VIwiQCcDod41ugLQgerik3yrHiEpZFLhjdmMBjuKbreE/hM74hBqvhGhyha/uma5AxxscmrCUIfXyj1GRZoYT8K/B1CYfHcqFULhTJbGGkB9Yv8OmK4Ud8rlSVe@WOROemkHssozp0ooVsp9MbwJEWFus8OT48R@NQMKomiBv34APzhbURuFvY3a9ms9X9Yonw3jYAq/4rPBQa28WWCNvSvVkoqNVEOG5/YMGlWIwWICBV09zOkyhmgdtG2PPGzoxFnLFW9wsl4Dko7hIGxcYXZmPN5M7EdwRV1ULJYNkzLvD91t3SWjvz6F/g65UgBHPC7XKyXiEnfeWGRDVT5xb7Jq9jCH@fla3SV9WWecMSxWa1FgchDy0@77eWQu8vTENEMe9PssVqYMng26Jp1r2Z4EuF28pAO7IIZ2B2yUvkxrzcZ7yJ7M1C6P2PQge/F/r4dINJcTfUFVfC@WKeoXfNFdIASC9QLAguYxeY0ZeIbWxBQOMS/4tV@AW2DkFctlgkyrdJRIzFjrFlUjW/ha19nWyxnMFzKaj/pPX1k465TRaL@1sugYoBM0JuE95FOahGoYzuHR@OZr3XXgBqBFYoLCnWYf/APexvumV3s1/mY42PIUezeIcFz0y9BeUA98fU3ixMO0SQFs51IRIrXJ979/p97g/XOTN@D8aHDzjbwXuRXatV33uh084YRraEJKR28/MXJpyVLnCWsHvlkjsOL@b4RRxB4fKCfpFlQ5b7@5htwqxoIeRx@PvJFAbE@P0y2HJtx3Xg6g15hlZItidoEFmu7YO4TOOW4G@aGtcoU@iTeNOX43lrJhnsTcV@c4DTWQfx3yXGrEOGA3bLBtBfAxcxtAtIrRdWGKZTPIIbf2WIRj1bccLewFFGndFYeQ0@DNsKHbKcg8Kf79QotHounJgLSwFmp/aoxE5O/HwmTa23F9CFLFPN08JuobS9UyghKbJkU9RnJ/Xj5K1hwTlD@PJ/5z/RmkSHPQRIALzwBU6SRB2OffAnoCBODxY2h4Ii6kSaTiz/CWJQm6Akc5Mv6Nd/AQ)

### Hint (posted after 5 days and 2 hours later, I think)

- This program uses a bug of my interpreter.

### Intended password

> `z317-35bP`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 57 bytes, [cracked by @the default.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231418)

```
class D(dict):__getitem__=0
exec("".join(open(0)),D())
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3zZJzEouLFVw0UjKTSzSt4uPTU0syS1Jz4-NtDbhSK1KTNZSU9LLyM_M08gtS8zQMNDV1XDQ0NSG6oYbADAMA)

Works under CPython 3.9.6. Takes input from STDIN and should output `uslcgtutmuexbwb` with a trailing newline to STDOUT.

*Hint: that string is completely random - it has no hidden meaning.*

---

The crack was not my intended one; [here's an answer with it fixed!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231421)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231418)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 70 bytes, [cracked by @the default.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231422/97857)

```
class D(dict):__getitem__=0
s=open(0).read()
if"."not in s:exec(s,D())
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY33ZJzEouLFVw0UjKTSzSt4uPTU0syS1Jz4-NtDbiKbfMLUvM0DDT1ilITUzQ0uTLTlPSU8vJLFDLzFIqtUitSkzWKdVw0NDUhpkENhRkOAA)

Works under CPython 3.9.6. Takes input from STDIN and should output `ryjtufbohqszxgg` with a trailing newline to STDOUT.

*Hint: that string is pseudo-random with no hidden meaning.*

---

@thedefault's crack was the same basic idea as mine, but it can be reduced to:

```
class c:
 from builtins import print
 print("ryjtufbohqszxgg")
```

As @thedefault says:

> Our code is being executed in an environment where trying to access any global variable (including built-in functions) throws an error.

The way around this is to use local variables, using an immediately invoked function, or more simply here, an empty class.

> However, import still functions correctly

This is because, when importing modules using the magic function `__import__`, the interpreter (bizarrely) doesn't dispatch to an overridden `__getitem__` method on the `__builtins__` namespace, but just uses normal built-in dict lookup semantics on the object. This is apparently not a bug, but an entirely implementation-defined quirk.

In fact, if you were a particularly good internet sleuth, you might have found [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue44643) which I posted to the Python bug tracker yesterday about this very behaviour.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231422)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 163 bytes, safe.

My output is `KDIITIWDRIKIDITI`

```python
import random
f=open(1,'w')
random.seed(0)
r=[random.randint(0,255) for l in range(255)]
a=input().encode()
for b in a:
 while b >26:
  b=r[b]
 f.write(chr(b+64))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoMwEEX3c4rsnFAJ1lYphfQi4sLoWAM6CWmK9PSpoV193uPx/Scuji83H1Kym3chijDw5DaYtfPEeC6LvZDwk@pFNGF1oO7@Jo/liFVZN40UswtiFZbzy5Mwux4Gbdm/I0pFPLqJUELuTO6GO4h9sSsd@Kjbg4TRoTM9iFntwUbCcQloTu1VSkjpCw)

---

My original password is `passthevoidsalts`

Since this basically follows a random directed graph (not a-cyclic, I just got lucky my password doesn't crash it) until it lands within a subset of nodes, it's straight forward to create a lookup table for each letter. Originally I tried to create a reversing crack, which works, but the .encode() on the input threw me off so I ran the process forwards to build a lookup table instead.

For each line output by this crack is the list of options to generate the corresponding character in the desired output.

```python
import random 
out = 'KDIITIWDRIKIDITI'
a = [c for c in range(127) if chr(c).isalpha()]
random.seed(0)
r=[random.randint(0,255) for l in range(255)]
od={}
odd={}
for b in a:
 ob = b
 while b >26:
  b=r[b]
 ch = chr(b+64)
 od[ch] = ob
 if ch in odd:
  odd[ch].append(ob)
 else:
  odd[ch] = [ob]
for c in out:
 print(''.join(chr(x) for x in odd[c]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBBTsMwELz7FXuLLVDUBtoipPSUS9QbQuIQ5WA7LjFKvZYTRBHi7WE3rYCL15rZGc84fk49hruHmObZnyKmCZIOHZ5A4PsEJWSHqq6f65fqqT7UFd0yoQluLBwxgQUfWPDq5LrYKfBHsH2SVuV@1EPstVStuBjmo3OdXCmRyuaK8PBhkqvbYrNRi@HwZ8hYK7Arv77pXAZvGN7QjwLQUA4j4KP3gyN4X2wJBVOmxrSCchDNYczN9l7RetfYviUMSbPkZCMyZhENZnMdowudREMCN4zuH8elkYx/a9P/EB0TN8iy/A19kPze@dLkfLVvbKvUPP8A)

```python
dpw
JKMPVWXacjqrvx
ABCDEFHLNRSTZbfhilmnsyz
ABCDEFHLNRSTZbfhilmnsyz
t
ABCDEFHLNRSTZbfhilmnsyz
e
JKMPVWXacjqrvx
o
ABCDEFHLNRSTZbfhilmnsyz
dpw
ABCDEFHLNRSTZbfhilmnsyz
JKMPVWXacjqrvx
ABCDEFHLNRSTZbfhilmnsyz
t
ABCDEFHLNRSTZbfhilmnsyz
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 141 bytes, [cracked by okie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235287)

```
from keyword import*
x=input()
if~-iskeyword(x)and x.isidentifier():
 exec(x,d:={"__builtins__":{}})
 try:exec(f"del {x}",d)
 except:print(1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc5BCsIwEIXhfU4RskqkFdxJoGcJ2kxwsE1COsGUUm_gCdx0o3fyNqLW9fsffPdnHOkU_LI8Mrl6_7q5FHp-hvESkuXYx5Bow0qDPmaSiqG71jisuyzq4C0vWxzQgid0CEkqzTgUaGWprG4mYcwxY0foB2OEnuZZMU5p1N_GCQsdn8osKqs-vxYi6ZjQk9ypH2q1_Y1v)

This is quite a long setup for what is perhaps a simple trick. Works in CPython 3.9.7. Given the correct input, it should print `1` (with a newline, to STDOUT).

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235287/101762)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes, [cracked by m90](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235952)

```
lambda x,y:x.isidentifier()and exec(f"{x}(1),1/0;{y}")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3zXISc5NSEhUqdCqtKvQyizNTUvNKMtMyU4s0NBPzUhRSK1KTNdKUqitqNQw1dQz1DayrK2uVNKG6tQqKMvNKNNI0lAoSi4vL84tSFAyVdBAcIyXNzGIFv_y8VKiOBQsgNAA)

Works in CPython 3.9.7. Accepts two strings as passwords. The flag is [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None), which should be returned from the function.

---

m90 got my intended solution. `y` was just a red herring

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235952/104752).

Answer (score 2):

## [ayr](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/ayr), 41 bytes

Not the most creative, but it makes use of some weird + unique behavior I discovered or wanted to use while thinking of something. I'm not sure if there are multiple flags that will work for this one, which **was** the case for my previous Arn problem.

```
%/=:"101&~:&:`;:,/.;`.'/ /%'#.,./&.`#&:=I
```

The desired flag is `4.368051189167166e_9`. This is a full program, so don't run it from the cli.

There is currently no online interpreter, but I'm going to set one up within the next couple of days, as the language is written entirely in JS. As it stands you can `npm i -g ayr-lang` and use `ayr <file of program> [flag]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 209 bytes, [Cracked by m90](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213963/guess-my-password-robbers-thread/237568#237568)

```javascript
p=v=>{try{a=[];(f=c=>c?f(c/6n|0n,a.push('![]()+'[c%6n])):0n)(h=BigInt(JSON.stringify(v).replace(/\D/g,'')));try{v=eval(a.join``)}catch(e){return false};if(h<1n<<10000n)throw'x'}catch(e){return v[0]===Math.PI}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc1PS8MwGIDxr1IHI@@LM60edrDNBPEywT@wYy0sZEmTUd6UNI2O2s9e9exz/sFzlkkOKrg@3pA/6WXpRRK7KYbLJEXdlGCEEjv1YEDlW/ouaCN5Pw4W2FXdAF6zWq231CDeF4RgxaNr9xTh@fD2yocYHLXOXCAhD7rvpNKQfzzl7YYxRCz/LknoJDuQ/OwdHY84KxmVBY1T0HEMlBnZDXounQFb3VJV3RW/EUYb/Cf7Yv98qotGCPEio@Xv@3lelKfBd5p3voUeVoc4GpO1PrM66BXi8gM)

Confused? Good.

Takes a JS value as input, flag is `true` returned from the function.

This basically resolved down to two separate problems - either expressing `Math.PI` in ~3600 bytes (10k bits) of [Jsfuck](https://jsfuck.com) which I wasn't sure was possible - My best attempt was around 4000 bytes; or making JSON.stringify error.

I intended to use a cyclic object reference - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5PS8QwFMS/ih4k7@GaVg97sH0riJcV/AMea2FDTJss5aWk2ehS@9lrFW87x5n5MbNXSQ06uD5esf8w89xTos0Yw3FUVNUFNKRpo@8a0Nmav3NeKdkfBgvivKoBL0WlL9ZcI97mjGDp3rVbjvD49vIshxgct645QkIZTN8pbSB7f8jalRCIWPyuJDJJdaDk3jve7XDSKmoLBsdg4iHwWaO6wUyFa8CW11yWN/kixmiD/xRf4qSfqrwmoicVrXzdTtOsPQ@@M7LzLfRQ/Qe1XPyFBUi0EKs/LC2vcP4B), but m90's idea of a BigInt also works, and probably several other things.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237568/104752)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 81 bytes, [cracked by ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238190/87606)

Let's try this again...

```js
alert("xx".split(new RegExp(p=prompt())).reduce((a,b)=>a+b,"").length>2+p.length)
```

The flag is `true`.

https://xkcd.com/2217/

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238190/64121).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 13 bytes, [cracked by m90](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238552)

```js
x=>x in x&&!x
```

The password must be passed in to the function, and the flag, `true`, must be returned from the function.

You can try solutions out in the (non-normative) snippet below:

```js
console.log((x=>x in x&&!x)(eval(prompt())))
```

Comment: Is a solution allowed to modify stuff before the function executes?

Comment: @m90 Yes [padding]

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238552/104752)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 57 bytes, [cracked by PyGamer0](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240414)

```
exec(input(),{"__builtins__":{"if":__import__(input())}})
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3LVMrUpM1MvMKSks0NHWqleLjk0ozc0oy84rj45WsqpUy05Ss4uMzcwvyi0ri42EKNWtrNSEGQM2BmQcA)

Works in CPython 3.10. Inputs via STDIN, and should print `Hello world!` with a trailing newline to standard output.

Unintended crack, so let's have another go.

Comment: [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240414/103854)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 62 bytes, cracked by @dingledooper and later @M Virts

```
exec(input(),{"__builtins__":{"if":dir(__import__(input()))}})
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY37VIrUpM1MvMKSks0NHWqleLjk0ozc0oy84rj45WsqpUy05SsUjKLNOLjM3ML8otK4uNhijU1a2s1IaZADYMZCgA)

Let's try again. Inputs via STDIN, output should be `Hello world!` printed to STDOUT with a trailing newline. Works in CPython 3.10.

---

dingledooper got my intended solution.

As for M Virts': dammit, I always forget Python can do that kind of stuff!

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240446/88546)

Comment: [Cracked??](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240549/100563) for some reason I just assumed the string was different from the import-only approach,

Answer (score 1):

## C (x86-64), 100 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214129) by @the-default.

This will survive until someone figures out how to run Xorshift in reverse. (So probably not very long!). Requires a key of 8 characters as a command line argument. The flag is **`CodeGolf`** followed by a line  break (and nothing else before or after). Liable to crash if the key is missing or less than 8 characters in length.

```c
main(int a,char**b){for(unsigned long *x=*++b,i=59295;i--;*x^=*x<<13,*x^=*x>>7,*x^=*x<<5);puts(*b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPIzOvRCFRJzkjsUhLK0mzOi2/SKM0rzgzPS81RSEnPy9dQavCVktbO0kn09bU0sjS1DpTV9daqyLOVqvCxsbQWAfCtLMz14EJmmpaF5SWFGsAjbOu/f//v3NGYl56qm/qv@S0nMT04v@65QA)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214129)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 52 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214169/44718) by [r3mainer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11006/r3mainer)

```javascript
i=>(a=+i,a<a/a?a/a<-a?1/a<a:a*a>1:1<a*a?a*a<a:1/a<a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchbCoAgEEbh7WgXwuhJNNfyUwpTZGIRtPpp6OHwwdnw4Foqlbu/Cq2xHmfe48vJM/lZwbfUwWFAkFyPYARYNJiNNU4Mkpz/ay6V8q2Smkat@QM)

Expect output is `true`.

Input via parameter, output via return value. Global values should not be configured before the function execute. (For example, `Object.defineProperty(globalThis, 'a', { get() { return ...; }, set() { return true; } })` is not valid.)

This one could be quite easy. I expected it will be cracked in 30 min...

Comment: Yes, it was quite simple in the end :-) [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214169/11006)

Comment: Yeah, pretty much :-D

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214201/92901) by @EricDuminil

```ruby
p eval($<.read.tr'Scfpvy.:?\'"%<`(',$/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhtSwxR0PFRq8oNTFFr6RIPTg5raCsUs/KPkZdSdUmQUNdR0Vf8///4sriktRchfTUkmJrhdSKzBJFrtTkjHwFdSUlJXUA)

Here's hoping I've managed to close the backdoor that @Sisyphus [exposed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214107/92901) in the [previous version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214106/92901). As before, input is via STDIN and the flag is `"""\n` (with `\n` representing a trailing newline) printed to STDOUT. Nothing is printed to STDERR.

---

My password: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhtSwxR0PFRq8oNTFFr6RIPTg5raCsUs/KPkZdSdUmQUNdR0Vf8///xJzMxGIFRYXc1JKM/JRia4Xi1LwUBa3oaEXv1KK81JzYaIPYaENDo1gdBRQhU5CIrl1xNTb1JuZASWOTWOymUSxraBBbGwsA) Same idea as the crack but somewhat different implementation.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214201/65905). Not sure if it was the intended solution.

Comment: Very interesting. I spent about 2h in order to find a solution which was very close to yours. I didn't like the fact that the methods' ID were hardcoded, and would only work on TIO and not on my computer. So I spent another 2h, trying to find a reliable way to access the methods.
Congrats for the interesting challenge BTW: it was, to me at least, just the right balance between frustrating and fun.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 67 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214294/98904) by pppery

```r
function(x) with(x, is.finite(a) && !is.finite(b) && is.nan(a + b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtBCoAwDAS/sl4kRS3oWR@TqsEcjFAr@vtavHgadpaJWTB2WS6bkx5Gj8OtaaOnhZ5e1DStxA51jeoX4RNlGxsxGgTnstDCib1E3kuCCX2LUDCU7wU)

The flag is `TRUE`. That is, find `x` such that `f(x)` is `TRUE`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214294/46076)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 66 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213962/guess-my-password-cops-thread?page=2&tab=votes#comment501732_214296) by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)

```r
function(x) with(x, is.finite(a) && is.finite(b) && is.nan(a + b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYs7CoBADAWv8ipJ8AP2episGkxhBF1xb7@uhWA1DMMcWTG0WS@fou1OiXFbXCk1sLNTc4sLCaOqfh4@d3ES1AjMWWmWKJ0espUDI/oG4UVpDw)

This is a slight (but significant) modification of [my previous post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214272/98904). The flag is `TRUE`. That is, find `x` such that `f(x)` is `TRUE`.

### Intended solution

> [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCU6E8syRDo0JHIbNYLy0zL7MkVSNRU0FNDYmfBOPnJeZpJCpoKyRpav5P08jJLC7RSFBTS1CwVYAbqKenp6kQEhTqClQCAA)
>  There are no two finite numbers that add to `NaN`. So we have to exploit the use of `with`. `with` uses the the contents of `x` to evaluate the expression. So simply redefine the function `&&` to be unconditionally `TRUE`.

Comment: I assume that [this](https://tio.run/##TYvNCoMwEAZf5TvJBn/qvem7ZKMu3UNXiCkVxGePuRQ8zjCTisD3Rb42ZV2Ndoef5jftHXQbRE3zQuzQNDeOfzY2YrSIzhWhmTMPkvhTD7xwhDb4PjzCczw7xGrGml0) is not the intended solution...  although I can't immediately find a way to rule it out...

Comment: Nice! Not exactly my solution, but still a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) + coreutils, 213 bytes, safe

```sh
n=$(shuf -n1 -i0-9999999);out=$( (eval "$(tr -dc '\t\n -/:-@[-`{-~')") );s=$((n**.5));i=1;p=Yes;while [[ "$i" -le "$s" ]];do;i=$((i+1));if [[ $((n%i)) -eq 0 ]];then;p=No;break;fi;done;[[ "$p" = "$out" ]]&&echo Win
```

Must be run as root on a typical modern Linux system. (so no TIO link). Telling you why would spoil the challenge.

Flag is `Win` with a trailing newline, printed to stdout.

I no longer have my exact intended solution, but you can use [this technique](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218524) or similar to achieve arbitrary code execution without alphanumerics.

Comment: Does the password have to work consistently?

Comment: @thedefault. yes

Comment: [Cracked but too late](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229544/100411)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes, safe

```js
OvUc^H
```

The flag is the array `[-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]`. I recommend setting the language flag `-Q` to see the output correctly, this is included in the below link as well.

Beware that the above snippet may result in an endless loop for certain specific inputs, but this is not the case for most inputs.

[Try it out here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=T3ZVY15I&input=LVEKeW91cl9pbnB1dF9oZXJl).

Solution:

> The program takes the input, XORs its charcodes with 32 and then evaluates the result as Japt. More or less any valid program that outputs the range will work once the program string is XORed beforehand. One such answer might be `"gçé"`, but interestingly also `"fOOBAR"`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes, [cracked by EasyasPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226211)

```python
I=input
X=vars(vars()[I()])
X[I()]=X[I()]
class I:1/0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39M2M6@gtIQrwrYssahYA0xoRntqaMZqckWAaVsIxZWck1hcrOBpZahv8P8/AA)

The password is 3 lines of input on STDIN. The flag is the following text, to be printed to STDERR:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".code.tio", line 4, in <module>
    class I:1/0
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

(replace `.code.tio` with whatever the filename of the program is)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226211/94093)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 157 bytes, [cracked by Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226441) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8294654)

```python
import sys
B,V,I=__builtins__,eval,input()
class E(Exception):0
B.exec=B.eval=B.__import__=sys.stdout=0
try:V(I,{"E":E})
except E:sys.__stdout__.write("win")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcy9CsMgFEDh3acITgoSAt0El4BDXiDrJU2FXkhV4jU/lD67tc10lo8TT3oGfysFXzGs1KQzsV6NajAA94wLoU8Aym3TotDHTEKyeZlSaqywx@wiYfBSd6xv3eFmU1NpDcB1BDD12SZ6hEymY7SeehSDenPLtf1I5v6XxuofA7ggQLuvSE7wHT2XpXwB)

Takes password via STDIN. Flag is `win`, printed to STDOUT with no newline.

---

@UnrelatedString found an unintended crack, which I had no idea existed:

```python
(_ for _ in ()).throw(E)
```

Turns out generators have a `.throw` method which inserts an exception into their call stack.

It is, however, sad that my intended solution was *also* more or less right there on StackOverflow:

> a python3 strong stomach solution:
>
> ```python
> type(lambda: 0)(type((lambda: 0).__code__)(1,0,1,1,67,b'|\0\202\1\0',(),(),('x',),'','',1,b''),{})(Exception())
> ```

Even if it was slightly more complicated than it necessarily needed to be (here's mine:)

```python
type(lambda:0)(compile("raise E","","exec"),{"E":E})()
```

We can construct the code object using `compile` instead of using quite so much dark arts, which is a bit less fragile. The `type(lambda:0)` obtains the class for user functions, which can be used to construct new functions using code objects.

Comment: [the crack post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226441/85334)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 24 bytes, flag "tab"

```python
print(input() % chr(97))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIzOvoLREQ1NBVSE5o0jD0lxT8/9/AA)

Easier than you think.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242870/107299)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 12 bytes

```
₌₃Ė₍¨=Ṙ‡2ȯJA
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigozigoPEluKCjcKoPeG5mOKAoTLIr0pBIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Flag is `1`.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248182/92689)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 163 Bytes, [cracked :(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263147/117478)

```python
import re
try:exec(input().replace("sys.stdout.write","print").replace("print","import sys;sys.stderr.write"))
except Exception as e:print(re.sub('\(.*\)','',str(e)))
```

The flag is the string `not a chance` with a trailing space then a trailing newline written to `STDOUT`, without using builtin functions or manipulating the exec function to do so to print a message.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcyxDsIwDATQvV8RZYmNoixsZeYvupRgiUiQRLYj2q8PqGRgOul07@quj5LPvadXLayGaVLeZ9ooQsq1KWBgqs81EljZJYjeS9Pw5qRkva2cstq/za/wdvx9yWUwYh4McaItUlVzPSKVbFYxNB8YmIK0G7gFwmlB553zogyEiL1/AA)

Comment: Can you clarify what "manipulating the exec function to do so" means?

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263147)

Answer (score 1):

## Vyxal `rS=`, 6.25 Bytes, [Cracked :(](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64034353#64034353)

```
₀Þ∞Ẏ*∆i
```

Better know your \$\pi\$ digits! The whole input must match the regex `\d+`, and the output is the exact string `8 8 1 3 4 6 3 6 4 1` with a trailing newline.

[Try it here.](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJyUz0iLCIiLCLigoDDnuKInuG6jiriiIZpIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## Vyxal, 151 Bytes

```
bṅṅB``τ ``βb→a
←a L8∆* →b
←aṅ \0 ←b ø↳→c
←c ←c L8 / / →d
←d2vβCṅ₴
```

### Flag

```
“Ò~pg‡lwAÓFX6ïå»NìðaÝ’
¾`Ç¿&X4óƒvþwßË^Ùî‚6þPsß·,²áç¿tzOÎ™qïÉ§vx6ïÝ¯/ž|2á×Ø÷òå—Mža
```

I was trying to make an encoder and decoder for monkeyspeak but the decoder was decoding incorrectly so I just merged them together and made a cop post for this challenge. I have no idea how the output works. For all I know, it could be a cryptographic hash function!

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJi4bmF4bmFQmDwn42M8J+QkvCfkLXwn5mJ8J+ZiPCfmYpgz4QgYPCfjYzwn5CS8J+QtfCfmYnwn5mI8J+ZimDOsmLihpJhXG7ihpBhIEw44oiGKiDihpJiXG7ihpBh4bmFIFxcMCDihpBiIMO44oaz4oaSY1xu4oaQYyDihpBjIEw4IC8gLyDihpJkXG7ihpBkMnbOskPhuYXigrQiLCIiLCIiXQ==)