# Guess my password (robbers' thread)

Tags: cops-and-robbers

*Inspired by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/210638/95792) challenge, which got closed. This is meant to be an easier, but no less interesting version of that.*

This is the robbers thread of a [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge. For the cops thread, see [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/213962/95792).

Cops will provide a program/function and a flag. Robbers will guess a password. When the password is given to the cop's program, the flag should be outputted.

### Robber rules

- When the cop's program is given the password you guess, it should output the flag.
- Your password does not have to be the same as the cop's password.
- You are allowed to take advantage of ambiguous descriptions of the flag by cops.

Cop answers will be safe if they haven't been cracked for two weeks.

### Example

Cop:

### Scala, 4 bytes

```
x=>x
```

Flag: `Yay, you cracked it!` (an object of type `String` is returned from the lambda above)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUM2loFCWmKOQZqUQXFKUmZeuYGsHZ/2vsLWr@A9RkF6aWlysYKugFFBaolCZX1oEFclILUpVAhpSANRSkpOnkaYBFtfU5Kr9DwA)

Robber:

Password: the string "Yay, you cracked it!"

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUM2loFCWmKOQZqUQXFKUmZeuYGsHZ/2vsLWr@A9RkF6aWlysYKugFJlYqaNQmV@qkFyUmJydmqKQWaKoBDSlAKinJCdPI00DrFRTk6v2PwA)

Comment: [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115404/guess-my-password-robbers-chatroom) for robbers to discuss answers.

Answer (score 19):

## [Sisyphus, PHP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213984/98889)

Password:

A string `golf` with 1,000,000 leading whitespaces and 1,000,000 trailing whitespaces

Output: `golf`

Reason: 1,000,000 is the default backtracking limit of PCRE (which you can get by `var_dump(ini_get('pcre.backtrack_limit'));`). And `preg_match` will return `FALSE` other than 0 or 1 when this limit is breaked.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7dBJCsJAAETRvadQCGRAzN4BjxIkdgaISaO98PbRe@S93ad2FYe4rtd7HOIu@966cQpNH1LTLnMKc/oU@X851/UnPcc5Ly@7sSsO8R365vVI7VDk9anql6k7VXV@zL5lGdph2af3@Cr@dVnXPQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAsFH9MnVeAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACArfoB)

Comment: Impressive first post! Welcome to the site.

Comment: Very nice! I've always found it amusing that PHP gives up and returns false when it reaches the backtrack limit rather than throw an exception.

Answer (score 12):

## [ovs, Python 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213978/39531)

Password:

```
class m:0
m.__init__ = hex.__init__
n = 49374
m.__str__ = n.__hex__
class a: __metaclass__ = m
```

Output: `0xc0de`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzfCsIgGMXvfQovgm0hEjWIHHuSVmLOUJpO/L6L7elNDLo5nD8/TtzRruGcs/NxTUiTYbADiWNRDji7wJNRc9sR9y4j9wq1bZvn3Wx6mm36vCZYnJejGBhXAeFxPDQsdsJsRtM4xOQCUpWzXhQA9eJEPJfSBYdS0pFas/0jCaXob5drXxnAVJFQfMHK/vtQgkrpDaoaK@K/)

Comment: Very nice first answer! I had [this](https://tio.run/##JYtBCsIwFET3OUUWQlspQbQgpvQkVj8xjSTYpCH/L9rTx2g3w8ybmbiRXcI5Z@fjkogn0@KGLA5FBdLkgkhGTXXD3LuUwivStq6ed7PqcbLp8xpxdh4G2bdCBcLH8VC1sZFmNZrHPiYXiKuc9awQOUrGAZASwNDdLteOCwBrVoAfd8FRKU4/uHu235QE8IbUP5UFfgE) which is basically the same.

Comment: Really cool problem. Keeping this idea in the back pocket for the next time I need to break out of a Python jail.

Answer (score 10):

## [R, Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214055/98904)

Password: `as.roman(c(1, 9)))`

It was roman numerals!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCr8D@tNC@5JDM/T6NCUyE5I7GopEhDqaqyorysVElHQSkIDICskvyc/PLUIo2KaMNYBW2FimijWE3N/2kaicV6Rfm5iXkayRqGOgqWmkBBAA)

Comment: Welcome to the site and nice first answer!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Very well done!  I've been struggling in vain with this for ages...

Comment: Ahahahahahahahahah.

Comment: Oh, that's clever! Well done finding it, and very nice challenge as well @RobinRyder. :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Lynn, Haskell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214033/64121)

Lynn created a stack based mini-language, the task was to generate the primes up to 500 in 60 or less operation. Here is my 55-operation password:

```hs
[0,0,2,1,4,1,0,2,1,1,4,4,4,30,0,2,0,2,0,20,10,0,3,10,2,0,3,1,0,10,3,6,6,6,6,5,4,7,5,0,7,3,10,2,0,3,20,2,1,0,3,0,3,30,2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/RisIwEEXf8xWFvCRrLGmqFYLxC/wDEQlaMdgNsXYlFf@9zqQ@1GW4M3dOkgu52Pu1bpphcP7sYiYpkTrQaAItdCQFev002GESlfY@EdbPIgdWfrF5Yosv9pPYcsJO7pH1GSZWE9rr5MjqH3uSI5IXu4mDbvl6fg/Ws/WRB9PSP9@5hjFjJM8vtT1xdqM8kgP8IZJf67xpgW79ZmNC63yXM7rb87yz1zqr5DDspJBCiUIsQKNDj1WORx9JUeBe4lCjEYmVovrUEh6toEvok3tqjEWLgli1fwM)

The available operations are

```hs
0   push 1
1   duplicate top of stack
2   add top two values
3   subtract
4   multiply
5   integer divide top value by second value
6   push the second value without popping it
7   swap top two values
c>7 while loop, runs until top of stack is 0
    the loops ends at the first instruction >=c
```

---

`0,0,2,1,4,1,0,2,1,1,4,4,4` pushes the initial number `500`.
The remainder of the code is best explained inside out:

`6,6,6,6,5,4,7,5` is a divisibility test. Given `k` and `n` as the top two values on the stack this calculates \$\lfloor {\lfloor {n \over k} \rfloor \cdot k \over n}\rfloor\$, which is only 1 if `k` divides `n`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc/vCsIgEADw7z7FgV@03Fh/tkiyJ@gNIkKaNdkysxUuevc17UvlgXf34zi4St5q1TR9r81Re8gwyrjFXlg84R5NQs2fIvxDRtPYd1FIN/Z0sNmPJdHmPzaKln9ZqR/QQdhYfGnHY4UWf/ZEhyAvcmV77ugquVlpyOpArXD4blrdECJERtNKyZKSK6Ye7YcbPEoSCM@ANCXUcLpApZwCeKCz1Ea4YX5j1mthnTZtSvB2xmC5o2krawVF1vfbgn0iZ3O2YPnuDQ)

---

`1,0,10,3,div test,0,7,3,10,2,0,3` is a primality test, or a composite test since this returns truthy (non-zero) values for composite numbers:

```hs
1                  -- duplicate n
 0                 -- push 1 - stack: [1, k=n, n]
                   -- in the next iterations of the loop,
                   -- the top of stack will be the inverted result
                   -- of the divisibility test
  10       10      -- while loop:
                   -- runs until [0, d, n] is on the stack,
                   -- where d is the largest divisor of n <n
    3              --   subtract top value (always 1) from k
     div           --   the divisibility test
        0          --   push 1
         7         --   swap top two values
          3        --   subtract (1 - div test result)  
             2     -- add the top 0 to the last k
              0,3  -- subtract 1
                   -- if the loop ended with [0, 1, n], this is now 0
                   -- otherwise we have a positive number
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc/hisIgAAfw7z6F4Be93HCtbSBzT9AbRISUNWnnmVvh4t59p3IHdQp///4UwV6OVzUMy6LNWXvIEGDcIi8sKrgHRez8KWKGFazTfk6C55Unwco3y5Jt3uwjWfViJ/2AM4wv1i8689RA88@e4BjlG9/ogTvSZqOVBrdHYoVDdzPpAWMhGMl7JU8E3xDx4BD@4EGWwb9h4OVLjbBXTsEH@JTaCBeub03XCeu0mXKMds2e5JO8KlizZdkVlNGC0ZLWv7OiG9qEZCHLeLQOtdz/AA)

---

`0,20,10,0,3,10,2,0,3,comp. test,20,2,1` generates the next prime less than `n`:

```hs
0                        -- push 1. This means the current number is composite
                         -- Even if it isn't, we still want to find a prime <n
 20                      -- while loop. This iterates until the composite tests returns 0
   10   10               --   we have an positive number on the top of the stack ...
     0 3                 --   by subtracting 1 until it is 0, ...
          2              --   and adding this to the last prime candidate ...
                         --   we can get rid of it.
           0 3           --   subtract 1 to get new prime candidate pc
              comp       --   check if pc is composite
                  20     -- end of loop, top of stack is now [0, p], with p prime
                    2    -- add 0+p
                     1   -- duplicate the prime, such that we store the result,
                         -- and can use the value to find the next prime
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc/RasMgFAbge59C8EY3E4xpUpDaJ@gblFKkdYs0c9ZkxZS@e6ZujHQK5/x@HA7YqeGi@36ejX0zATIEmHAoSIcqEUCVsrjLVGMHPL@nLHh6DSRa/WRFttWTvWRrFnY2NzjBtLFd6CRyAut/dgenJA98pUfhyaYYnLJ4cyJOevRlR9NjLCUjZafVmeArIgEc4x8CKAr4dyx8/9QD7LTX8AY@lLHSx/md3W6l88aOJUb7hvEDKUd10bBl87xnlDNaMcponRr/CTRbTdvf29AVXcfKYl3M8RSqwzc)

---

`30,0,2,0,2,next prime,0,3,0,3,30,2` repeats this until the prime `2` is found:

```hs
30              30  -- while loop
  0 2               --   add 1
     0 2            --   add 1
        np          --   find the prime less than this
          0 3       --   subtract 1
             0 3    --   subtract 1
                    --   if the prime was 2, this is now 0
                    --     and the while loop terminates
                  2 -- add the 0 to the 2 to remove it
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9va8MgEMbf@ykE3@hmgjFNClL7CfYNSinSukaaOWuyYsq@e6buD@nuuOee@3EcXKeGi@77eTb21QTIEGDCoSAdqkQAVfLiLpPGDniep0zw9BxIZPUDKzJbPbCnzJoFO5kbnGC62C7oJLID63/sDo6JfOIrPQhPNsXglMWbI3HSow87mh5jKRkpO61OBF8RCeAQfwigKOBfWHh@1wPstNfwBt6UsdLH/Re73UrnjR1LjHYNY3tSjuqiYcvmeVczyij/LUarNNep8W9DM6tp@5MNXdF1VBZ1sceTqbJNFc/y/Rc)

Comment: Looking forward to future answers with "Lynn's stack based mini language from the crack my password thread"

Comment: Good job! I hope you had fun cracking this (I aimed for that much more than I aimed to write something uncrackable).

Comment: @Lynn It definitely was a fun program to write. Working with a stack, especially with this limited number of operations, is an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 6):

## [R, Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213985/46076)

```
5.099829245500619335478113833945732102551318887107339446461762721i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcg7CgMhEADQq1hqE@brzBS5xeYEC4KNwq6B3N4kr3zXbumZdnuPc/U58qekPtYxX6t5Puf9i7Jb1gdEOAWJKkDFYFYxR2RnDlFjQiBVZHR3Q7B/S5WKVskIe9lf)

Comment: I think `5.1i` would work just fine...

Comment: You're right. Wasn't sure how precise it needed to be, and Robbers' answers aren't graded by size.

Comment: Yes, `intToUtf8` will not only discard the imaginary part of a complex argument, it will also round down the real part, which is why `5.1i` works.

Answer (score 5):

## [Sisyphus, Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213991/78410)

Password:

```
[1.1071487177940904,1.1071487177940904,1.1071487177940904,1.1071487177940904,1.1071487177940904,1.1071487177940904,1.1071487177940904,0.897846510365972]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//cFtIwP///6MN9QwNzA1NLMwNzc0tTQwsDUx06C9koGdhaW5hYmZqaGBsZmppbhQLAA)

The code `OÆTP`, when taken literally, means `product(math.tan(ord(c)) for c in input)`. But the ord function in Jelly does nothing for numbers, so we can ignore that. Now the problem is to generate that *very* specific number. I figured that as product is likely to have precision loss, I'd use 2's as multiplicands. The number `1.1071487177940904` is equal to `arctan(2)`, and I use seven copies of it to reduce the problem to `arctan(x)` where `x<2` so that I have better chance at getting that exact result. Finally I computed `arctan(answer/128)` and put it as the last term of the input array, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Very nice. Of course, I did not intend this to be cracked =) My solution was `BVp6o0|zX\`BrJ?w<C/gv(jZz36wdQr*M@R^7jqov\`D_O05!~:G`

Comment: @Sisyphus Yeah, I quickly figured it would be basically impossible using string input. Blame Jelly for the sidestep :P

Comment: Actually, it seems you can make Jelly print anything by doing `print(160.58880817718872),__import__('sys').stdout.flush(),__import__('os')._exit(0)`. So Jelly is useless for this C&R.

Answer (score 5):

## [att, Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213979/98349)

Password:

```
flag /: Head[flag] = flag
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78r6yvr5cYb2XnkZqY4pCoFv0/LScxXUHfSgEkEA3ixCrYKoDo/7H6@gFFmXkl/wE)

.

We can adapt this kind of solution to work with any Mathematica program:

```
a /: _[a] = flag; a
```

With this argument, any function returns `flag`.

Comment: Nice. `UpSet` is a bit shorter, but of course `TagSet` works perfectly well.

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238174/64121) by tjjfvi

The flag is: `()*` (Or `()?` / `(){0}`)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcYxFsIgDADQq/iYElsZ3NvNC3iDFPIQxZAHqPT0dPFP/0lfqq5EbZeq0XN5Z3nxPobLUnNim3IA07uxVVNsIPw73TncuoIuhcmnKAyIaAv7j2MAmjdcVpq22Ri0iSW0x3qd9F8cA/B8AA)

This splits between the two x's (it matches the empty string) without actually capturing anything with the group. The return value of `split` includes capturing groups, which results in `["x", undefined, "x"]`. This gets reduced to `"xundefinedx"`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Sisyphus, Python3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213987/11006)

All you need to do is keep the processor busy for more than 9 seconds.

Any regex that requires lots of backtracking will gum up the parser. The only real difficulty is not slowing it up so much that Tio runs over its 60-second limit.

```
'b(.*.*.*)*z|baaaaaaay'
```

[Try it online here.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoVackMzeVK8k2M6@gtERDM9rKxCCWK9EWJKoHIjQ0uYpS9XITS5IzNJJ0kjS5MtMUkCR1E@0srQqKMvNKNAw0//9XT9LQ0wJBTa2qmqRECKhUBwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey), tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213997/48931)

Password hexdump:

```
61 61 61 00
```

(3 `a` followed by a null byte).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYy7CsMwDAB3f4U2JxTjdMnW/otiC6I8bCGbkkL/3W0TbrnhuAnL3BqFOYPFhxLGjRN1vRHlVDu8YW/hCSFHMubKxvufYbDwgeOI4BSc/NxnqX7BF5agLNUV4Ui657TS20@c/FLOT2tf)

Comment: TIO: https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEtLshMSS3Kzc/LTq38/z/Rtig1MSUnMy9VQ5OroCgzr0QjUTtREyiRmMgAAA

Answer (score 4):

## [Eric Duminil, Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214092)

My password is

```
14127792144400463565475544498208881214759697720904563865426051592050217695592754443713601541725640031x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000123456789
```

According to the Ruby documentation, to_i discards everything after the first integer it finds.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY9BCsJADEX3nqJ01Qodk8wkmSx6kiKCUKWbKraF0cvXqYI3MItPPi8/8B/L@bmuqb3287S7L/NUVKkD59zYJjcNr/5ARzffTsM@daNzDX5dvelUeamL4VKkrrEPa9sSyQcWjVauKwYkVSMMIQAE8SwclDlbiwQxRsxM2cRUCQxy0sd8QwKMbAQMhCrGedct5hW9AHJAJZb81GOCf82vyhs)

Alternative solution:

```
9164214512877268290754278122624834497733309914632715416260853069873976599113800182718102190123456789
```

I factored the semiprime with cado-nfs.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1JCsJAFAX3niJkZYS0f@o/LHKSIIKgkk0UE6H18nECNwWPelC3@@GxLKU7H@dpdb3PU7UuPaSUxq6kaXget7RL82U/bEo/ptTibzUfTmvWphpOVenb@Lquq5FYsppHvSyBKoSSkdyM1CnAspA5EimJs0iYMTNEoCiTYRZUUvDMoOHGYZrfEtkB0N8HRyAM@Gde)

Comment: That's interesting. As far as I can tell, the two large factors I used were primes, at least according to sympy. Do you have an example of the found factors? Did you check their product? Well done, by the way. That was the intended solution. I blame the documentation.

Comment: @EricDuminil Indeed, it seems like I did something wrong (the most likely explanation is that I accidentally removed a digit from the middle when copying the base36-decoded result from Mathematica and removing the line break it inserted)

Comment: @EricDuminil A better program could still factor the number (in around 865 seconds).

Comment: Wow. Colored me impressed. I had no idea how to estimate the time it would take to factor the semiprime, and I didn't want the target to look suspiciously long. Do you know how the required time scales? How many more bits would be required for the factorization to be 3000 times longer (~1 month)? Even then, I guess that throwing more CPUs at the problem could bring the required time to a few days. It wasn't a bruteforce question anyway. Again : congrats.

Comment: @EricDuminil I used the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers to check if it's feasible to factorize the number (and it said that a 100-digit prime can be factored in 72 minutes on an old CPU). It seems that a 250-digit number is the largest one factored, and it was factored in February 2020. It also seems that it took them around 2700 core-years and they used cado-nfs.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214153/44718) by PkmnQ

```javascript
({toString(){return this.i--;},i:43})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtBDoIwEEWvMiYuIAEWysJg0EN4ASpOYUyZajvFGMLZa6OJu//@y7urWfne0UPK@RCjbrk98aatd@duu/AK5EEBh@mKrmv@l4wIiv0LHYj9UjBCkxKEZ0AvZBmsBkMai59mmtH5RIpvgGm/ZSQeuthb9tZgZeyQ6WwRexGXRJYvDiU4Tjn5isryuBbU1Ps1z@MH)

JavaScript variables like: `({toString(){return this.i.shift();},i:[1,2,3,4,5]})` would be useful in many [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) answers.

---

```javascript
({valueOf:()=>43,toString:()=>42})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcpBDoIwEAXQq4yJC0jQBbIwJIUjuPACVJxCTZlqO60xhLNXIom7//7/Dxml751@8iGeU1KCREM7UZVtt59pAe1BAoXphq6r/xWPCJL8Gx2w/SkY1pNkhFdAz9oSWAVGKyy2mXRE51dJugOu@cOjpqFLvSVvDR6NHTKVzVGagBdVZ7loqlPB9spu/W0ulzxPXw)

It is strange: While, let `p=({valueOf:()=>43,toString:()=>42})`: `''+p` results `"43"` but `` `${p}` `` results `"42"`...

Comment: The latter is my intended solution.

Answer (score 4):

## [ZippyMagician, Arn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214040/11006)

Password: `J0e_Biden!`

I'm sure this isn't the password that ZippyMagician was thinking of, but it works at least. The flag is equal to 2<sup>96</sup>, and the uncompressed code starts with `:*:*`, which raises something to the 4th power. I'm not sure what's going on in the middle, but the last few bytes of code (`:i0^:i"n`) calculate the value of *a*<sup>*b*</sup>, where *a* and *b* are the indexes of the characters `0` and `n` in some transformed version of the input. So if the second character is `0`, it's just a matter of tweaking the input until the `n` is in the right place.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/), [ovs's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218895/69850)

```python
@print
@int.__invert__
@len
@ascii
@ascii
@ascii
@ascii
@ascii
@ascii
@ascii
@ascii
@ascii
@ascii
@str.lstrip
@min
@ascii
class a:
 pass
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY5BDsIgFAX3nKJdAY0hJt1VMRzEhOAvRgz9EMBGbXp2bFx4ATfzZvUy8VVuAftaQYZoke25SNaMjJOlg/W4dPSMzU4MB6m0ucBor@7uJwwx5TK/6drK/gQCwgMLo@BNzpS30j4tMOC1qpgcFqI2CK0dzjYVrYnyFokyGZz7e3JJwm9wkajJ/W6/LY0ZSBM3@QA)

I used a brute force program to find the solution, although in the end it ends up being quite nice: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVTLctowFF1bX6GIBRJxHNNONk7dCdNV990RxiNsuSgxskcSFEz4dnolPxLSRVl40H3fc47UHO2mVl8vl8nN/Vqq@8afkdw2tbZYKtOI3CL4yRLHCQoaLZWlRlhK8o0m7O40mz4rHEbJY/qU8XVeiFK@VFtVN9rYfTs9MxRoLo3Ac4Ta9HRGCEIwLwrahljxrWBQFqqfZu5w/vbfghAeWH1MsErFnlfU1wCbOOSisQnWwu60AgMUlQVVDKvarYJblxm0S29cpT4RRmCwXVlrnLuYQmqaZeudrCwsn2X9cN5H6kYo7BGAwiQyTSUtZQnOawXRO4GCfq2cdSWLrkXhspezNoJxd8JQtoKqbgWYx4U1zr/n2tCC@RmhY5OmJMuMbEVdZhn52CQY2pTk5Duco1NzJoDBAEHDjYGt4CuARUp4VZEQw5f9M0mIW5RXEIkXfZ4WPN/wdSXSEyC1gP0oJQsSshAv2NmzV1bc0kOPjTSAlOUqF/QQYrtrKk@p34y7focEH6WoClzqetvlcjdsZcTgOSDvy@uqAr3JWhncS/BHvVNWaGSPjchyd0h7E2XICKEyIGQrrdyL1MmSocmfjawE/qV3IvEsSAjmrqgbRnP1W9B5HLNRzeTnEJBggGkMZ916wzFNH9xaoOHXBO@xq/wawh@nrAiitgCnI8cl7ZfxyjmoNwQE2kRZJtUe@AA2w97MTS4ltCSVUIMRIEYeO1lkIaZAhVQhrtcvAEzm@RsJivK6OVI2NHfTTaA5uSMuzFhNh7SBj7ITZNkNPYjAa66/UuWY44yDoD6K7/O1GsfxZQKbOqqoGrHwQRQQCN1IXTPvAETv5vGXh94ysFECvcUNYdfWJ4JvMbwMT9PopZaKagFYGlHQ5cwryuPEVgxUSp7Vs3p7Gyv0SjJH8@g@kTi4a/s@hgfrSknXCwfBtTdy1889G87lVTzWelfp0q6@pw9xHH@udRVym867MpNuzSnu1/M7DeR71phfDdbyT5bLGYEfX7SreIhD6HL5Cw)

Initially I found one with `__sizeof__`, but it doesn't work on TIO (being implementation-specific).

I had to made quite a few tweaks for it to fork (disable `open` and
`id`, as the former will read from stdin with `list(open(1))` or something similar)

It's also possible to get `import inspect` and quite a few other modules, but I didn't consider that possibility.

In retrospect, `repr` would work as well, but `ascii` comes before `repr` in my generator program.

Comment: My intended solution used `__sizeof__` and there was `@print` `@len` `@str` `class aaa ... aaa:pass`, but this works as well :)

Comment: @ovs Good point, I didn't think about changing the class name. https://tio.run/##7dNBDsIgEIXhPadoV0BjiEl3VQwHMSE4HWNNHQhgozY9OzZew36Lf/eWL7zzzVNbCmgfkMReqoiuF5LNDSzHueFnqnaqO2hj3QV6vA738UE@xJSnD19q3Z5AgX9SFhxGlxKXtcYXggBZiglxoMzMGmXtQBPGbC0zIxIzKUf2m1Rus9n8hy6sl/8C

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js) by emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237515/104752)

```javascript
[Math.PI, 2n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NSsQwFEZfZVxI7sWa1lnMwjYjiJsR/AGXtTAhpk2GcBPSTHSoffbqgDu/7TlwvoPMclTRhnRN/kMvSxBZbKcUT5MUbVdDL5TYqrseVLmh74oKycNxNMAu2g7wirXqckMd4m1FCEbc22FHCR7fXp75mKKlwfYnyMijDk4qDeX7QzkUjCFifa5kobN0IPnBW9rvcVYyKQMap6jTMdKql27Uc217MM0NNc26@h1hMtF/si/2z89t1QkhnmQy/HU3z4vyNHqnufMDBGj/QLFan28vPw)

`JSON.stringify` throws a `TypeError` if it finds a `BigInt`, thus executing `catch(e){return v[0]===Math.PI}`, and then it is simple to make that true.

Comment: Nice! My solution was to use a cyclic object reference, but this is pretty much it :P

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript by tjjfvi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238444/104752)

```javascript
document.all.toString = ()=>"length", document.all
```

[`document.all` is an object that is unique in several ways, including being falsy.](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers.html#sec-IsHTMLDDA-internal-slot)

`in` uses `toString`, so the first part can be made true by changing `toString`.

Comment: +1; this was the intended solution. (Though my version was `document.all[document.all]=document.all` :P)

Answer (score 3):

## [HyperNeutrino, Python 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213965)

Password: `import sys;sys.exit()`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCoAgEEXXeYpwo4JE0c7oNDHQgNlkEyXR2c1aPPjv8yjxvIY@53NGD3XnRMUxOT9ioIO1ERVcExCXR6lPYNLe3o@9JVzI0rVWbsc/nhJTxMC6MznjQmvkek/7UGi@WJsX)

Output: nothing

I'm not sure if erroring would be OK. It would not output anything to STDOUT, only STDERR.

Comment: I should've specified, i intended no output to either STDOUT or STDERR, though I'm not sure if the challenge permits me to do that. Raising an empty SystemError would've worked too though, but this is a good solution.

Comment: also `import os;os._exit()` which is effectively the same thing

Answer (score 3):

## [HyperNeutrino, Python 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213965)

Password: `raise SystemExit`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/vzwjMydVwdCKi7OkqNIqxzYzr6C0REOTizO1Ijm1oAQooq4O4qQma@ToVNfqVCulVmSWKFkZ6CgVloIZtUDFBUWZeSUahpr//xclZhanKgRXFpek5roCVQIA)

Output: nothing

Answer (score 3):

## [ThisIsAQuestion, Python 2.7](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15100/thisisaquestion)

```python
True=False
The
Flag
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BDoMgDIbvfYqGjAQWs8OOS7j6BN50W9DhJFFgCHF7egbxZk/t169/3S9M1lxT0ouzPqBXANo4FOjl9sxdDIyDHtHYsrwsMgwT8@TRdlv3EvfziVSYNX4DzPWJuvjqqwZWKIA8RPWHeZzlO6OsCeyhfNqJwMZHtac6r01ghK5IV0KZrLDnPKUiiFrOq4JmUlDnuz8)

Output is `The Flag`. *Sadly* reassigning `True` doesn't work in Python 3 anymore.

Comment: Dammit, I was seconds away!!!

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), cracks [Nahuel Fouilleul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213976/17602)

Password: `"^^@@^^:@@@^"^".,).*||,!'|"`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8nNS@9JEND08bIQkFNTUFRP6ZcH8RILUvMARP//yvFxTk4xMVZOQBJpTglPR1NPa2aGh1F9Rqlf/kFJZn5ecX/dfMA)

Answer (score 3):

## [SE - stop firing the good guys, ><>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214022/64121)

One password is

```
5 8a*3+o ab*1+o ab*1-o aa*1+o ab*6+o aa*4+o aa*5+o ab*o aa*3+o 48*o ab*5+o ab*1-o aa*1+o aa*8+o aa*8+o ab*5+o 48*o aa*o aa*1+o aa*8+o aa*5+o aa*1-o aa*5+o ab*1+o ab*7+o ab*5+o 95*1+o 95*1+o 95*1+o;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PQoOD/f1MFi0QtY@18hcQkLUMopQukEmE8M20wzwRCmUIEwWyQLhMLLbCAKabWRC0LJAqiBKI8UQuLKlMIBTXBFMVF5ggTLE3BgiiUNQA)

The program was `i10p`. `i` reads one character of input `1` and `0` push `1` and `0`, and `p` changes the value at `x=1, y=0` to the inputted character.

Whit the first input the program is modified to `i50p`, which allows to execute arbitrary commands from input.
`0-9a-f` push their hexadecimal value to the stack, `*+-` work as expected, `o` outputs a value as a character and `;` terminates the program.

Comment: That was quick.

Answer (score 3):

## [Kevin Cruijssen, 05AB1E](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214006/64121)

The password is

```
2
,*xžIž?¶
```

The `.E` builtin seems to push the Python code back to stack when it failed.
The first input is just any number for the loop. The second input is a reversed 05AB1E program to produce the correct output:

```python
¶        # push newline character
 ?       # print without trailing newline
  žI     # push 2**31
    žx   # push 2**6 = 64
      *  # multiply these numbers => 2**37 = 137438953472
       , # print this with trailing newline
         # since there was explicit output, implicit is now disabled
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P8wNWFiMWX//0Z9xb5o0Lw5wqMuRVIuVir//zIKLCp4xb5Jxb4/wrY)

---

After some more experimenting, I found a cleaner password:

```
3
print()
3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/frfbovowLeywPLdZzDdIL0/r/35iroCgzr0RDk8sYAA)

`.E` executed on `"print()"` returns `None`, reversed is `enoN`. This is then executed as 05AB1E code, which seems to return the right result. I'm not sure how though, there might some features of the legacy version used here that I don't know of. Beacuse Python was used to print the newline, the value is still implicitly outputted.

Comment: Nice, the second is indeed the intended solution (although I had `print('')`, hence the head to 9 - didn't realize those quotes could be removed, but makes sense). As for why this works: in the legacy version of 05AB1E the `F}` that loops `N` in the range \$[0,3)\$ will remember this `N` if it's pushed later on (in the new version it defaults to `0` outside of loops). So `enoN` will basically execute as those builtins: `e` (\$\frac{a!}{(a-b)!} = \frac{3!}{(3-3)!} = 6\$), `n` (\$n^2=36\$), `o` (\$2^n=68719476736\$), `N` (pushes the `2` from the last iteration of the loop);`*` (multiply).

Comment: Another solution I realized would also work later on was [this one](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/frfbovowLeywPLdZzDdIL0/r/34BLh0tJSYnL0NjcxNjC0tTYxNwIyAcA), but well done finding the intended solution, as well as another alternative! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [SunnyMoon, !@#$%^&*()_+](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213975)

```
1728
```

I read the code, and it seemed to parse decimal input, divide it by 48 (not halting if it's not divisible) and print the corresponding character 3 times.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P9fK05DVUEhXlsrTlNVwyBeW1UTzI1T0VCJj4sHY21FGNCGgTgVTW2gFEilikZ8HBzEq4BkKirAwgbaEK6iooODw///huZGFgA)

Comment: Exactly! Congratulations! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 pre-release, pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214073/46076)

```
("unittest.mock",("mock","sentinel","pxeger","name"),())
```

Probably not the intended solution.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU5BTsQwDLz3FVa4JKuIA3BARfsA3rBaVd7UaSNSJ0odYF@/hAA3Th7P2DOTr7ImfnzO5eZL2sBXdpJS3CFsORWBw3AHF3JYd4JXYKIZkP9EFJCVYBcsYmGPwRHU3DmXZgJJsJBA4njtZHcPieEjtNgq4FbkJfDS1Ui8yArJ923DwN1l8Ed6x6iVUv93PLxE3C4zAtqLdaOex2OhuToy@lcg60c6@bN1dtatEYqUdjtNPwbTpNEYc2sJp4en8WyGIZfAor0@9OjAuYo23zdaVQ4itMv9ltybslr9TLUTS2CKDeZPWqg0wLiRMra9fgE)

Comment: Aww I knew there was gonna be some kind of bypass gadget in the standard library. Not intended but more-or-less the same idea.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby, Dingus' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214106/48931)

```
system gets;exit
echo '"""'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X1E/Ojg5raAsRs8qxl5dSdUmQSNWX02tQCO1LDFHJV7z///iyuKS1FyF9NSSYuvUiswSrtTkjHwFdSUlJfV/@QUlmfl5xf918wA)

Comment: Very creative! If you're interested, I found a pure Ruby solution (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213963/guess-my-password-robbers-thread/214201#214201) which works for both challenges by dingus.

Comment: Actually, I don't get why `system gets;exit` somehow breaks out of Ruby into the shell. Could you please explain?  Is it specific to `ruby -n`?

Comment: @EricDuminil Dingus' first answer only reads a single line, so only `system gets;exit` gets read and eval'd. The second gets call then reads the line `echo '"""'` and passes it into `system`. The exit runs after the shell has finished executing the command and terminates the ruby process to avoid the `p`.

Comment: Dingus' second answer reads all of stdin at once, so this trick does not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I couldn't seem to understand that `gets` retrieves the next line. Old-school debugging helped me understand it : https://tio.run/##nZLfS8MwEMff91ecUdfuYdv7nIgPRUQHQos43Ni0vc5Adwn5MTrEf93YdpusVB/WQAJJLt/P5Xun7PvWubVIbIYw6QAoTDkhPKAizCARxRFAging5i3z8161B5DWaGD9fwarRQXPt48jOP/MB5y0xNh8He61lagOokjJL0y2Iz39jckb@is0@iR9Bde7bGuv7oIoLJGqgVQNpN5qg@t2/wqnYRRMTvQQc27aVOvlPqppHwmXazmt5rQq2iUWZJBM4c3FonM2fA3jVG5mg9HsxmOX46U/H3a70i87B/ahPed2RlQluKpyxPhDgMcY876FNFyQdn36AQ

Answer (score 3):

## [r3mainer, C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214125)

I'm really sorry, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31515396) answer on Stack Overflow has code that directly undoes elementary xorshift operations... It made running xorshift in reverse much easier (I only had to copy-paste some code and write 6 lines of Python).

```
07RtUrVE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPIzOvRCFRJzkjsUhLK0mzOi2/SKM0rzgzPS81RSEnPy9dQavCVktbO0kn09bU0sjS1DpTV9daqyLOVqvCxsbQWAfCtLMz14EJmmpaF5SWFGsAjbOu/f//v4F5UEloUZjrv@S0nMT04v@65QA)

Comment: Oh bother. I actually did a quick search for reversing Xorshift on SO and GitHub and came up with nothing. Should have looked a bit harder, I guess!

Answer (score 3):

## [Conor O'Brien, Javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214185/36445)

```
^^^Z_][_\\\\\]_\\]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]_\\\]_\\\\\\\]_\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\]b_\\\\\\\\\]aa
```

The code seems to generate a random maze (the seed is based on our input, but I don't use that) without loops. We must solve it (in at most 999 steps) with a program in a stack-based language with these 8 commands:

```
0, rotate stack: S.push(S.shift())
1, pop twice, compare and push difference: [a,b]=S.splice(-2);F=a==b;S.push(a-b)
2, increment register: M++
3, push register: S.push(M)
4, pop and discard: S.pop();
5, reset register: M=0
6, pop to register: M=S.pop();
7, set answer to ToS and halt: R=S.pop();O=[]
8, pop pop() numbers, and if the last equality comparison was true then
   insert the numbers into the program: n=S.pop();n=S.splice(-n);if(F)O=n.concat(O)
```

The program receives its input as the lengths of the lines of sight in 4 directions, and must output one or more commands in base 4 (digits 0 and 3 are errors, 1 is "rotate left" and 2 is "move forward").

My algorithm checks if the line of sight to the left is zero; if it's zero, then it rotates right (by returning 21), otherwise it rotates left and moves forward (by returning 9). I might have confused left and right completely, though.

Our "program" is obtained from our input by concatenating all char codes in it (as decimal integers). However, nines are discarded. So I used characters with codes from 90 to 98 to access the commands.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVYNb9o8EP4rfIjKbowX2Ca9bXZUbbdW00aZgOndlnlbCAFSkUDjlA@B99e7s53Q9n0XCXK2z/fx3HMHt8EqkGEWL/NmuhhHD8tskSzzClQIrUCngsswkpIH2XTlt4X38AWIzznvCTYAX1Do7OZRXumyKxawEeuz1OvCFbjeehbPI9Lj8yid5jMarYI5IbWzAZezeJITSus@XhDVNvWuIAAYeWdBc0TrXcepn3VpvVHvgoufRr0PjR66qqfQSKsp9eIJuaI9SHm4SMMgJz1a43I5j/Nf9V9@r7Qv9vtajfIsWs6DMCIvGi@mrDbgy8WSUO/pwfez4uRezsjTg6reh4GxjetmjVIvi/L7LK30lYfOZV75DBYvQosQfvEkWJJIQxfxcBZklwjquc6X3y7iFM8P9k@0/VpxkWjJXIWOE1GvDzt52nZZcupu/nHtw4LTVst9@br1uv3qNQtPW@2X@J4i/HeE7srQuATS58ExCsdOn4e00eeJYjFZPdG5e/G7idvHq72rjIXRUwsxaVPFZqbQgaC7ySIjMfxuBkU1vbjjenGzSXe3oLVjp0U9P/BjwQL/Vgjw9YvpDaEKq4FSno7tMwIwvsf8yZKFSJ@lEzKXeuE8kLIy2BlYs/swR5drloJLd/kslnwNa88IKaRWkLBTVgpRUjdkCHp1SCON1pUBGfI1G/KUqk@Hc52N5myMLI3foIIXOw5FVlWHPMSQ6ZCfk1jfwu2y4kPVJZLlrDSiDZyDviAFuzBCLrwhl/65APva7327c2F3Lh53zoWlG@JrT2ihaCgQYlNpg6GAc0W9cYTOoopVUAOi@@w/uWrtQIAJYyTUOQmZPOgUpqQDtZpxI2088jEeWcQTUnXsD7bJaDHncR5lAZZBIDO2cTQfH/dGt1GY8yjNsziSxFaBqm9kApNgLqNn4FxilCFbsRuWsSmbs8S7xCb2RuCH4ApPF8EL3/xuavxDBHqHBRjyAUYeIpv2e1KdHB31@YjS3aUNbkTNbaclVITeMK9uoe2NivBRVupRfaU93mCyN8SMjerkUH0/ZlIsJpWhjfbO8FgW/G62rPodvXMcb4pnMyKxUc0ccNkdWj7Ub0q9aVm1G66RjykGkWnXl@VBaAQSsZgFZmQCtgzAoZ8SqM6P216yh9YxWfE4HUeb3oREtAqgg8msu4Sqwwzyb/gnQlkmlMyDPA4rV2QNLZfN8MvmJMG2wJpaTTYF328JwTTxDf7xG8v9qe8WBGgx9Pa8QWZGZedL9AWSf8NJAGAgmh5AeE8yTLog4xQ7XV9/DyRjFezr3NKj/K14CxgFe6e/MbGS8G@tMZc5hIRHbQrY@tR7Z3fNXsvsYYDqgMFb9k6oYnZcPJ8dj1gYniY4yBEhNqN2ZmSYmxGuAa9EVp4QqgKyMSzmG7a1wvbQZtaSvxX@RqgJeWywDXJsi59oC63il2/IA4Llc3GabJBEeFbYTTTYJc@eKGuN4kK0aTbVv@S53w3Y@9Hm6MjGVW5s1ZhkVs4Od3zfZQiz32wxF18ua@qVXggfSfORFMBkGJwVGvBKXRHLnUWJwbLAgI2tMCYFgBsHxpiJXWz1AsuJTWPWmDpAq/CwgUWhBcsSc0MIVapjqtRUbzGP@HwxJbV1nNboc2UcwDq7Ik8n83TAhmgJ9shjfBll/6tgAXMRG@4j0BhemUMZfuI4JYkTNSQTi0UikarsJXNZW7AVTEgiy19qY7CLfYpUtS5WRXGubfJ@7cPHqw81f9V4JQQfYWObICiiuOp0oK2eVvha9UufX@Hk5ORp1NdHR1@bzY5LzUrHphTR/X2h/1r0SQCdL@QzThf68PDw48ePbz@F//O7fgS@xN@en8XhQevvjxg9Hokg@AM)

Comment: That was cracked way faster than I expected :) very nice! :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Dingus, Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213962/guess-my-password-cops-thread/214164#214164) and [Dingus, Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214106/65905)

One password for both Ruby challenges by Dingus is:

```
G=->*x{i=0;i+=1 while x[0][i]!~x[1];x[0][i]};Q=method G[methods,/^[o-q]ri/];C=method G[q=Q[],/[o-r]ut[b-d]/];D=method G[q,/^de/];P=G[q,/^[o-r]\z/];D[P]{|x|};C[34];C[34];C[34];C[10]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYtLC4JAFIX/yhSFPXxSq6aphYFbpeXtRg8nGijUSU1L@@tmGRRtDufxHZns8qoKCU@3p15nqku@9fVYKsv9IUxzfTJfKe3udNNT1I7RryqHabNBdhfMpGLILHI9ihMnGZgIAluPDCykn1RSj515fAx84kBjLqqxhkCLUAoDqf2dI@YBqka9SUxi2Gk@1sDiB6ifPq87lzXhja5uLwpcvBdZUVIbRmP8U8vEJw) & [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYvJDoJAEER/BYy74kD05Dh6wMQrxGPTrmCYBAEBFQX8dEdcEo2XSi2vouPmIoRMYL7dhSerN7QmjUpttGoiqdfDpnNae9VlS4gZU8btNONMpbzDNOnscs@RUlAROMq3FDSkn1RQk@2dxA1saQZvE3fJAgLlgBEnSPXvfGAmYJeUW4THBDaKjSUw/QHKp@2UncHe4YVa1ycFBmZ5mhdUh/4A/1RT8R6ECQ/8WCj@Aw)

- Gets access to [`putc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-putc) by listing all the available (private) methods and filters them with regexen.
- Also redefines [`p`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p) to not do anything.
- a lambda is used instead of `def`
- `method :method_name` with `[]` is used instead of `()`
- `.` cannot be used, so only the methods for `Object` and `Kernel` are available
- Since `putc` is available, any string could be written.

FORTRAN like code:

```
GREP = lambda do |l,r|
  i=0
  while l[i]!~r do
    i+=1
  end
  l[i]
end
PRIVATE_METHODs=method GREP[methods,/^[o-q]ri/]
PUTC=method GREP[PRIVATE_METHODs[],/[o-r]ut[b-d]/]
DEFINE_METHOD=method GREP[PRIVATE_METHODs[],/^de/]
P=GREP[PRIVATE_METHODs[],/^[o-r]\z/]
DEFINE_METHOD[P]{|x|}
PUTC[34]
PUTC[34]
PUTC[34]
PUTC[10]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhtSwxR0PFRq8oNTFFr6RIPTg5raCsUs/KPkZdSdUmQUNdR0Vf8/9/9yDXAAVbhZzE3KSURIWUfIWaHJ2iGi4FhUxbAyBZnpGZk6qQE50Zq1hXBJQGCgGltG0NgYzUvBQgCZLjAjEDgjzDHENc431dQzz8XYptc1NLMvJTFEAWREPYxTr6cdH5uoWxRZn6sVwBoSHOKIrQDIiO1dEHqi6KLS2JTtJNiQVqcXF18/SDKSCkNy4lFWSLLU55sOExVejmRgfEVtdU1NSCHRhtbBKLi2FoEAsA)

Comment: This is a very nice solution!

Comment: @Sisyphus: Thanks. That's also the most horrible Ruby one-liner I've ever written.

Comment: Very nice! Same idea, different implementation.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214226/67312)

```r
function(x,y,z){if(length(ls(1))>1|length(ls())!=3)return("S");LETTERS[lengths(lapply(y,intToUtf8(x),z))*lengths(lapply(y,intToUtf8(x+32),z))]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCr8D@tNC@5JDM/T6NCp1KnSrM6M00jJzUvvSRDI6dYw1BT086wBsHX1FS0NdYsSi0pLcrTUApW0rT2cQ0JcQ0KjoaoKdbISSwoyKnUqNTJzCsJyQ8tSbPQqNAEmquphU@FtrERWFFs7f80DUsTHUMdQyszzf8A)

The password is pretty insecure: `94,(numeric vector of length 1),(numeric vector of length 6)`. In particular, `94,1,1:6` was what I used.

The first thing I did was note that the `lengths` have to multiply to `18`, so we need to generate two lists such that the `lengths` are equal to `1,18`,`2,9`,or `3,6`.

Next, noting the `intToUtf8(x)` and `intToUtf8(x+32)` I found all pairs of functions that satisfy that condition with [this script](https://tio.run/##K/r/v0LBRlchsaAovyC/WENJT1tJJzc/JdVWKa00L7kkMz9PSZOrEqQkJ7GgIKdSo0KntCTNIiTfM69Ek6sKSaJSJ0E7QcfYSJOrHCRaDBGt0snMKwnJDwXq0eTiqoguV83MU62I5SqHsf7/BwA). I safely ruled out `nrow` and `ncol` since they would generate the same values, and the `lengths` must be distinct.

After that it was a matter of just trying things out; `lapply` always returns a `list` with length equal to the length of its first argument, so `y` had to be of length `1`. Luckily, R recycles, so `lapply(1,"^",1:6)==list(1^(1:6))`, which has `lengths` equal to `6`.

Finally, `~`, the `formula` builder is very odd, `x ~ y` is a `formula` with length `3`, with three elements, `'~'()`, `x()`, and `y()`, so `lapply(1,"~",1:6` is the same as `1 ~ 1:6` which is also length `3`.

Comment: Congratulations! [My solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214226/86301) was of the form `67, factor of length 3, vector of length 3`, using the functions `c` and `C`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), breaks [pxeger's challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226206/94093)

```python
__builtins__
SyntaxError
__build_class__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39M2M6@gtIQrwrYssahYA0xoRntqaMZqckWAaVsIxZWck1hcrOBpZahv8P9/fHxSaWZOSWZecXw8V3BlXklihWtRUX4RF0QiJR6sOj4eAA)

The first line loads the dictionary of Python's builtins.

Then, we assign `__build_class__` to `SyntaxError`. Why? Because `__build_class__` is called like so

```python
__build_class__(<class_body>, "class_name")
```

While `SyntaxError` is called like so

```python
SyntaxError("msg", (filename, lineno, offset, line))
```

When Python tries to call `SyntaxError` as if it were `__build_class__`, it tries to index the class name as a tuple.

Comment: Exactly what I had! Well done!

Comment: Can I ask how you worked out to use `SyntaxError`? Was it a bruteforce search through `__builtins__`?

Comment: I mean, I can't say my answer didn't involve *some* brute force lol. 

Answer (score 3):

## [Python, pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235272/101762)

Input `__debug__` and magic!

```
from keyword import*
x=input()
if~-iskeyword(x)and x.isidentifier():
 exec(x,d:={"__builtins__":{}})
 try:exec(f"del {x}",d)
 except:print(1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5BCsIwEEX3OUXoKhEruJNAzxJsM9HBNgnpBFNKvYEncNONgkfyNqLt9v334T1eYaCzd_P8TGTLw-duo-_4BYarj4ZjF3ykDcsVupBISIb2VmK_7iLLozM877BHA47QIkQhFeOQoRF5a1Q1FlrXCVtC12tdqHGaJOMUB_V3bGGg5WOeiq2Rv18DgVSI6Ejs5RK1ts1vrQ3U6aT1Ar4)

The condition are `not keyword and is made of a-z,0-9` and also can't be `del` while not being a builtin function => builtin constant?

Comment: Well done, that was my intended solution! (sidenote: in Python 3.10, `del __debug__` will be a `SyntaxError`)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235949/104752) by pxeger

`assert`, `int`

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3zXISc5NSEhUqdCqtKvQyizNTUvNKMtMyU4s0NBPzUhRSK1KTNdKUqitqNQw1dQz1DayrK2uVNCG69xcUZeaVaKRpKCUWF6cWlSjpKAH5SpqZxQp--XmpUFULFkBoAA)

An [assert statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) can take two expressions; if the first expression evaluates to a true value, the second expression is not evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

## [Aaron, Vyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237451/101762) (Not intended)

aka this solution is not correct.

```
.dI:⅛kF*×u⅛Ė.SṪḢ42f÷₍+*Π¾J∑Cøṙ
```

input:

```
1.2
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

`1.2` Make program have exception and the top of the stack is the flag.

`1.2` can be any float.

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=.dI%3A%E2%85%9BkF*%C3%97u%E2%85%9B%C4%96.S%E1%B9%AA%E1%B8%A242f%C3%B7%E2%82%8D%2B*%CE%A0%C2%BEJ%E2%88%91C%C3%B8%E1%B9%99&inputs=1.2%0AEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238164/31957) by [tjjfvi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87606/tjjfvi)

Input:

```
((x))
```

I'm not 100% why it works, but it seems that JavaScript insists that all capture groups appear in the split. Because the same string exists twice, it is captured twice. This is consistent with, e.g., input = `(((x)))`, which lists each `x` three times. Furthermore, what occurs before each string seems to also be preserved:

```js
> "Hello".split(/(He)(llo)/)
[ '', 'He', 'llo', '' ]
> "Why Hello There".split(/(He)(llo)/)
[ 'Why ', 'He', 'llo', ' There' ]
```

In any case, either behavior is enough to cause a discrepancy between the length we might intuitively expect (2) and the actual result.

Answer (score 3):

## Cracks [pxeger's python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240413/103854)

```
__builtins__['if'].stdout.write("Hello, World!\n")
sys
```

[Attempt it Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3LVMrUpM1MvMKSks0NHWqleLjk0ozc0oy84rj45WsqpUy05Ss4uMzcwvyi0ri42EKNWtrNSEGQM1ZcNMcWWe0emaaeqxecUlKfmmJXnlRZkmqhpJHak5Ovo5CeH5RTopiTJ6SJldxZTEXRD8A)

##### Explanation

The code `exec(`s the first input, and `exec(`'s second argument is the dictionary which contains all the variables / functions in the scope of `exec(`.

What I did was simply import `sys` and access the library using `__builtins__['if']` and print to stdout.

Answer (score 3):

## Vyxal, [cracks emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248177/92689)

```
`555`
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigozigoPEluKCjcKoPeG5mOKAoTLIr0pBIiwiIiwiYDU1NWAiXQ==)

Infinite possibilities. Wrap any palindromic string that is at least 3 characters long in backticks.

Comment: That... shouldn't've worked.

Comment: Also something like `×3*` would work. Any Vyxal code that will yield a palindromic string that is at least 3 chars long.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), cracks [Scott](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97730/scott)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213977/95792)

Password: `{length:"0"}`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v9K22NZOI8e2WC8nNS@9JEPTPscqRz@nxvB/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGpUY1RNpKQclAqVZT8z8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Aryan Beezadhur, JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214042/64121)

The password is `defined`.

Using [this reverseengineering.SE answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/10951) I was able to able to decode the JSFuck back to normal JavaScript:

```js
if (prompt('Password') === ([0][1]+"").slice(2,9)) alert('cracked!')
```

The password needs to be equal to `([0][1]+"").slice(2,9))`, which evaluates to `"defined"`.

Comment: You just need to execute `eval = console.log.bind(console);` before the bf code. And these text will just appear on your console.

Answer (score 2):

## [ovs, Python 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214082/97857)

Password: `"".format`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQfaeIFvkhImgTQSeJEIMioVScMYhhzm7vxQ@v4McpplJgcT5mlKqyAEfC2gckDdySFlKtG7Hg6njtLaEjYcye3Y3OgzFiJmYltaZhHliV0jT9GdJj8Qc)

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in mind. Your TIO throws an error because you have an empty command line argument.

Answer (score 2):

## [tsh, Javascript (SpiderMonkey)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214152/11006)

Password: `-0`

Output: `true`

Answer (score 2):

## [R, Paul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214272/46076)

```
data.frame(a = 1, b = 0/0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtBDkBAEAS/0i4yGyzuPGYWE3MwElb4/dq4OFW6OnUkwdAkuWyKuhs9DrfGlZ4aenpR07gQO5Qlil@ET@RtbMSoEJxLQjNH9nLwlhOM6GuEjK7t8vsC)

Comment: Ah. Good job. I didn't mean for it to have such a straightforward answer. I'll add a new question with the hole plugged.

Answer (score 2):

## [Dorian, dotcomma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214176)

```
[49375, -1]
```

Of course, the cryptic response in the comments turned out to mean "no, it's not a string". I think it's a big problem with the answer if "it would become too easy" if you told me what IO format I must use.

I noticed that the code seems to ignore all the input except for the first number until it finds a negative number. Then I noticed that it subtracts something from 49375. I don't know how does the code work, though.

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/dotcomma/?p=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)

Comment: Good job. The intended solution is only the number 49375. I had the idea to use the decimal value of 0xC0DE, but somehow messed things up and ended one number to high. I will write a detailed solution when I'm back from my vacation next Monday.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3, pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231421)

Object-oriented programming is always the best solution.

```
class c:
 def f():
  from os import system
  system('echo ryjtufbohqszxgg')
 f()
```

Our code is being executed in an environment where trying to access any global variable (including built-in functions) throws an error. However, `import` still functions correctly (I don't really understand this part of Python, but I suppose it's because `__import__` technically isn't being removed; it's just no longer accessible by the normal means). But just importing a necessary function is not enough: once imported, it will become a global variable, and these can't be accessed!
And the following fix doesn't work:

```
def f():
 from os import system
 system('echo ryjtufbohqszxgg')
f()
```

because once `f` is declared, it also becomes an inaccessible global variable! Fortunately, classes are executed as normal code when declared, and variables declared inside them are not global (and therefore are accessible).

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Lc1BDoIwEAXQfU8xYUObKGFpSNgR956gwTKFGmGwUxLwKm7Y6J24jZi6-_nJf__1GZfQ0bCu7ynY42k7m3vNDJVsnAmq0LrF4AL2Wpe54JJGHGSuMo91I5VwNsmSgQK4AbjAGY3kQyWVitofXbdLVE0hoEELVqo9gfXUAzG4fiQfgBfej_Y-Bpmi6Qj8cguTvVL34OfctqkSv7mI8hc)

Comment: An alternative to using a class to call the function are decorators, which have a lot less restrictions since 3.9: [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Lc0xCoMwFMbxPad4uJhAK44lIHSQbj2DxOQlpqixvgjaq3Rxae_kbSrU6Zv-v-_9HZbYhH5dP1O058t2060igpIbr6OQVeUw-ohdVRU5oyIM2PNcZCMqwwXzNsmSPkTwPZDEGTWnU8mF-GsHum73a6u62ihw0u2ZQQuWC8nAjqGDQOC7IYwRaKH9ix3LU9RNgHF5xMnWoXnSa3YuPfAf)

Comment: Nice, although it can actually be a bit simpler than this. (see my edit on the cops answer)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3, pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231469/64121)

```python
e%e#d¹F¹S
z(1,42)
A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;J;K;L;M;N;O;P;Q;R;S
T;U;V;W;X;Y;Z;a;b;c;d;f;g;h;abs;j;id
```

<sup>`¹` represents a byte with value 1</sup>

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY7LSsNAGIXpdp5iGBEyEIuKC-khC2_1Xq31jjBM_vnHRGomJFNQX8VNNvpOfRurdXvO4fvO53f9HotQdd3XLPq17fmMMgqvdTnlhAZZqLlK1lPV5Er3G7Yu0alSqeI3pr-knlpaLIOh4DgjLWzbchPVKETpQyNjwdLbsooyeFmwXVRlJalvjAtkjPgFJaSX8v8P3fyJV3nF9Ya9ifhINtKtTS12sIs97OMAQxziCMc4wSnOcI4RLnCJMa4wEde4wS3ucI8HPMIiB8HB4xkFbN7iBaVbSn4A)

The input first needs to pass the `exec` call. This checks the syntax and creates tables of constants and names:

```python
co_consts = (1, 42, None)
co_names = ('e', 'z', 'A', ..., 'id')
```

Then all the bytecode is replaced with our input, the relevant part is the first line:

```
e%   101 37   LOAD_NAME   37 (=id)
e#   101 35   LOAD_NAME   35 (=abs)
d¹   100  1   LOAD_CONST   1 (=42)
F¹    70  1   PRINT_EXPR   1 (argument is ignored)
S     83      RETURN_VALUE   (exits the execution)
```

---

without any comments and unprintables:

```
dAdAFFS(71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY89TsNAEEb7nMJyZUuPyPtj7yxSijQpaTiAZdYbJVLwWo4jwVlo0sBNOERug4G0873vzczH1_g-H9JwvX5e5v2D3C5hE9LreDzFIjxu0hiHoiKfXvJyPcWuL0rynDy-xfA3GU9dWMjUhtTHTShX3fkcpzl_SnO2T1M2H2K2747DnKV9dojdEh2HLKzbtk-hbVe_oiKU_8vvN1xv3_223-52z4VTOI0zOIurcQ3O4QTnkQpRiEYMYpEaaRCHCOLxFV7hNd7gLQqNwVKzGBA8qkIplEYZ1ALUqAblUILy6Aq9dDTaoC26Rjdohxa0x1QYhVmUBmMxNabBOIxgPLbCKqy-P_UD)

The first 8 bytes are actually executed:

```
dA   100 65   LOAD_CONST  65 (=42)
dA   100 65   LOAD_CONST  65 (=42)
FF    70 70   PRINT_EXPR  70 (argument is ignored)
S(    83 40   RETURN_VALUE   (returns 42 and exits the execution)
```

Comment: A bit different from my solution, but great work!

Comment: Actually, the sequence `F¹` is interpreted as `PRINT_EXPR` with the 0x01 byte being its (ignored) argument, not as `PRINT_EXPR` then `POP`, because [all bytecode comes in `(opcode, arg)` pairs since Python 3.6](https://bugs.python.org/issue26647), and `RETURN_VALUE` is actually returning the `abs` builtin. The `RETURN_VALUE` also interprets the newline byte following it as its argument.

Comment: @pxeger I see, that knowledge would have helped me a lot while creating this answer, it was a lot of trial and error ;). Is the second part closer to what you had? I assume this can be done quite a bit shorter

Comment: I've just edited a write-up of my solution into my cops answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3, pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233207/64121)

```python
f("(lambda **k:k)(a='b')", [12, 14])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc9BboMwEAXQq1izaGaQm5aqixTESRCyjDGqFcdGxkQg5JNkk01zp96mtKK7Wfz39ef2GJb46d39_jXF_vn0_eh0z3ocuaQif0Hn45qBOCZIT2s2JipVpfxlMFZvGQAOetYKqJyrdolahiAXVEflhfKdprJ-7X1ghhnHJPs959o0xtUfTVMGHafgmL5Ku5GgByuVxp3-1Y04E_EVhGgnY6NxoxBQrCnRvjYfgnERNxuwR0ArL20nWZadizOhrA7tgYCzOn_jLH9viHb4_-4P)

The challenge consists of two parts, first to create a dictionary without `}` and any builtins, and to get code compiled for `exec` to return a value.
The dictionary can be created using named function arguments.

The instructions in the bytecode at the indices specified in the integer list are set to `NOP` (9).
The expression compiles compiles to the following bytecode, if we remove (convert to `NOP`) 12 and 14, the dictionary is returned.

```python
 0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <lambda> at 0x10f79ad40, file "<dis>", line 1>)
 2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<lambda>')
 4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
 6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('b')
 8 LOAD_CONST               3 (('a',))
10 CALL_FUNCTION_KW         1
12 POP_TOP                  0
14 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Excellent work! I used type annotations instead of function call kwargs, but you got it!

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235305/100664) by EnderShadow8

```javascript
function a(){this.i=0;this.toString=()=>this.i++?'is':'constructor'}
f(new a())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZltha5ecn1ecn5Oql5OfrlFdG10RC0Qampr/00rzkksy8/MUEjU0q0syMov1Mm0NrMGMkvzgkqLMvHRbDU1bO4iUtra9emaxupU6yLiSotLkkvwi9VquNI281HKQCZr//wMA)

A bit of a  mess. This uses the fact that `Object.is()` called with no parameters returns true.

Comment: Very clever, but sadly not my intended crack. Do I reveal it now?

Comment: @EnderShadow8 You can either reveal it now, or create a newer version without this vulnerability. Then again, if your strategy was just to modify the value of x on getting the value  so `{}[x][x]()` returns true, you may as well reveal it.

Comment: @EnderShadow8 Also, if you simply have a neater version of this without the constructor, you may as well reveal that - I just couldn't figure out how to mantain an obkect's state without using one.

Comment: It's not too far off actually. I'll add my intended solution to my answer

Answer (score 2):

## [FZs, JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238206/87606)

```
o=Object.defineProperty;o.a=window;o.b="x";o.c=o;o.get=x=>i++==0?2:i;i=0;o
```

This essentially encodes

```
i = 0
Object.defineProperty(window, "x", { get: () => i++ == 0 ? 2 : i })
```

Once run, `x` will return `2` the first call, `2` the second, then `3`, `4`, `5`, etc. This means that `x === x && x !== x`, as `2 === 2 && 3 !== 4`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), cracks [@pxeger's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240438/88546)

```py
__hello__
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY37VIrUpM1MvMKSks0NHWqleLjk0ozc0oy84rj45WsqpUy05SsUjKLNOLjM3ML8otK4uNhijU1a2s1IaZADVuwiis-PiM1Jyc_Ph4iAgA)

Coincidentally, `import __hello__` is an easter egg that outputs the exact text `Hello world!`. As such, the first line of input doesn't really matter here; perhaps it was used as a red herring.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. I hadn't intended for the rest of the code to make it possible, but I forgot you can access the variable `__builtins__` as PyGamer0 did.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 62 bytes [cracks @pxeger's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240438/88546)

A generic escape from exec with no `__builtins__`:

Uses the class heirarchy to go from list to object, builds a dict of subclasses of 'object', finds BuiltinImporter and imports all of the builtins again.

module name doesn't matter, must be a valid module.

```
{x.__name__:x for x in [].__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()}['BuiltinImporter']().load_module('builtins').print('Hello world!')
csv
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY67CsIwGIV3nyJ2SQLaWTo4OOkTOJTy08tfDKRJyEUipaNP4dJF36lvY2l1O3wcvnNeH_PwN63G8R18uz9MR4xYM6FM8Izv-gSgCkJ6oRxAkvWJaJOsEZYBiM5o6wH-Zc6Hga-Wn2ycnn1MAVTZIUAWSastiUQokhczrmXpZuucqtLhElyoFoozZ3zI6WkdvyxbaGnBeCp12UCnmyCR0f87ylNjhfKMnlFKTa7aymZL-aZ29_XNFw)
(yes, the code on ATO prints the wrong key)

Answer (score 2):

## [I am kind of a language dev, Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263146)

```
[c for c in [].__class__.mro()[1].__subclasses__() if "os." in str(c)][0].close.__globals__["write"](1,b"not a chance \n")
```

Classic pyjail escape. Of course, you could always use `from __future__ import braces` or `raise Exception("not a chance ")`, but that's more boring IMO.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BasMwEEX3OcWgjTXFiITu0nVPYRsjK5NGoEhiNKbx6V3Z8aKrgcd7n8mLPFL8XFf/zIkFmE7Cy5Ve5LSPeRaNhikH60irshRT5JZmMb/shVSrMvso6p/zBq069mrydWTEfGSIJ3o5ygLf@/Epgi1A1z3WTKbMk256bT56bNqmaYuwJkRc187BPTE48BG6wYyjC7aUcTRPThq7y4ZqvVOqXCP4O6hUjNqSbcjh0J0H40IqVO2fkCYbqtqp93uDvrSTiknAgnvY6Aj6qPAP)

Comment: Don't forget import sys as s works too! :P

Answer (score 1):

## [pxeger, Python 3.8](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213972)

Password:

- A = `eval`
- B = `print("the_flag")`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsIwEETv/YollyaXXLyItkIDevUTJKZpu1A3IVmLfn1tC4q3YR5v5m7zMDvLcAJPE6ZAhf4l/4ohMTTfYIr45iHQTu@hqs7Xy4yPDYR8lO5Qh6x7z4stRSOU0pix9cTYoU9SWWrBAQUGJBETLoDik8Xa@8mO0in5t2CWhXn9aOqVFqYuN0kKHvytG20vVPkB)

Output: `the_flag`

Comment: Nice! I was thinking about using the thing where `print` is considered the same as print in other Unicode letters

Comment: This was not my intended solution and I realised it as I was sleeping! But well done!

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), cracks [Aryan Beezadhur](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94032/aryan-beezadhur)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214038/95792)

Password: `fine`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcs7CoAwDADQq1QXE/yg4ODSk4hDSaNEayutCJ6@@va3m8ckinLdbbrEcjyDP/jNWVYFkY114hlQaa0VzP0yD0tdltglJ8QwNhOiouBTcNy5sEFF0dDBtqgw5/W/Hw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3, ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214079/46076)

```
[x for x in ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__() if x.__name__ == "Quitter"][0]("a",True)()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpLCsMgFIXhrVyc5N4QitBZIIsodBaCaDFUsCb4KBZx7VYy@/nOOX/xfbh7a/orLRp3pog0lUEIlYyNxgUhhrnUSjiOhc@8Umtrhv3wkME4QLoJ8bIy9GMvJYO@IiR1qe6OBGaH3NXJT59hWYA9kolRe7atfEMm2fT0SRPSHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [SuperPizz, BrainF***](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218914/72733)

Password: `` ej`aH ``

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwSi7XSidXV17bRtYu30bGx0Y///T81KSPQAAA)

[Python script used](https://tio.run/##PY3BCoQgGITvPsUQLOlGEEUdgo5Br7FYkheVPyl6eteSmtsw38y406/WNCE4WnYMqJj7bdthaY4mz5myBAltkB3jUk1ZzxA1a6ViHikuBUrc5QJ1293xO1EMkCtxfvECXzT4XJBIVHpMI8yRNp4/TRHCHw)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226439/85334)

```
(_ for _ in()).throw(E())
```

Yep. Apparently generators just have a throw method. [Found by searching SO for "raise exception from python lambda".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8294654)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) + coreutils, [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger)'s [post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214916/100411), cracked after being safe.

Password.

```
${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)} ${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}${(#)$((){<<<$#} $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VrbToNAEP2VCV1btma1PPigC4lf4KsxbRN7WcLGZqmFaiKpv46D/oAPbcXdAw@QMDuzZ87cIHxURdu6TMRVsc9JuYSUnajbn0Pqcl/zM4rN22JDkYjrHan1ikazeuZIXd@p@6l6btTnSEaSpK5YOHbj8dWNlNpmid5mT6bS74XdGJpOWYONSPF9JKqI5nO9LlmM19jLpFuRd0KdigsrJSnzSpNOqi6MY1UPpV7uzOJF55YXOqO/NW4jyvjCO@00DodmVZT0aF3biiYeSNYmmzRNxeBAwpdTHvzFFib6cBiVjMx7qH2i8y/28jubIZexsLCHy3QIyENqXsdGenrf@WABMY7ucWq0PlnpQ5ycw3Z/bPibkaHNbmHzjY8r6JuYxI/rLcz4iK7ze9I3O75X0v9pA@wDbf/8h/dC5AVwoaKh74Fv1ObwfhHCZAp2sQ9wDdzAhIkDvAIv0CJzUZORl8DrnwdRm3yM9C8)

### What original program does

- Generates one random integer: 1-9999999.
- Variable p should represent if the integer is prime.

### How I cracked

- [If tr was cat, then password would be like this](https://tio.run/##LU/NasMwDL77KYRJS9zgkRx2KCJ9hF7HKD14qYJFg93Wzjb28qncTBcJ6fvTX/LLEvqqTn4ewYYOLLd2v5bBOGe5QU3fbgJd1YPLRhswmGRdh93u7d0Y5L7DW/9JCX88TwSnk2BZg5VZV0nD@YyXKDDhcNMVxlhARWLDxoClO7QFlT0FkTpG/HqQu@LIQgyEL8Wbhl6aZCqK2y0NPsIHh2WRAGoOmScQg8N/LHWJanCJVpumKUYcoDXqRTxGRb@cESm5QRWXdS9vPAE); the password just immitates what the original program does.
- But I had to `eval` the string when `tr`'d.
- [How password has to be encoded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110648/fewest-distinct-characters-for-turing-completeness/218524#218524)
- [Password generator](https://tio.run/##vY3LCsIwFET3@YpLjTRXSakLF5IqiHv3QjehTW1QktLEBzb99lhQf8HdnOEw83JtjLYGvjfA7/62Cr4HfnCQ8w2UpQnnXnWQBfm4QDp0vTa@SejAZkgZw6EoCjobE9HYngmacy6@CtAEfxnHZEwD@xCou7yGfzx@AVJIRSU9xqi3K3IzXl@BMb0zi0W2RiS1JZV0CqZ5M18uNSJoAzkSVbUWjpaop/ZCKCeryTXq05@UewM)

Comment: [Password could be shorter](https://tio.run/##7VrbToNAEP2VCV1btma1PPigC4lf4KsxbRN7WcLGZqmFaiKpv46D/oAPbcXdAw@QMDuzZ87cIHxURdu6TMRVsc9JuYSUnajbn0Pqcl/zM4rN22JDkYjrHan1ikazeuZIXd@p@6l6btTnSEaSpK5YOHbj8dWNlNpmid5mT6bS74XdGJpOWYONSPF9JKqI5nO9LlmM19jLpFuRd0KdigsrJSnzSpNOqi6MY1UPpV7uzOJF55YXOqO/NW4jyvjCO@00DodmVZT0aF3biiYeSNYmmzRNxeBAwpdTHvzFFib6cBiVjMx7qH2i8y/28jubIZexsLCHy3QIyENqXsdGenrf@WABMY7ucWq0PlnpQ5ycw3Z/bPibkaHNbmHzjY8r6JuYxI/rLcz4iK7ze9I3O75X0v9pA@wDbf/8h/dC5AVwoaKh74Fv1ObwfhHCZAp2sQ9wDdzAhIkDvAIv0CJzUZORl8DrnwdRm3yM9C8 "Zsh – Try It Online"), as in next comment (cont)

Comment: (comt) [this](https://tio.run/##LU/NasMwDL77KYRJS9zgkRx2KCJ9hF7HKD14qYJFg93Wzjb28qmcThcJ6fvTX/LLEvqqTn4ewYYOLLd2/yqDcc5yg5q@3QS6qgeXjTZgMMm6Drvd27sxyH2Ht/6TEv54nghOJ8GyBiuzrpKG8xkvUWDC4aYrjLGAisSGjQFLd2gLKnsKInWM@PUgd8WRhRgIV8Wbhl6aZCqK2y0NPsIHh2WRAGoOmScQg8N/LHWJanCJXjZNI0aKg2rNyjtGRb@cESm5QRUTte7liyc "Zsh – Try It Online").

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3, pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231417)

```
[].__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()[81].acquire.__globals__['__builtins__']['print']('uslcgtutmuexbwb')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BDsIgFET3nsK4ARJt6sY0Ju56C0II4LfSUKjlE-tZ3HSjd-ptJLW7mXmZmfe3f-E9-Gn6JLwdqvlknIpxW9OrNcjOUjaAFqGT8lJuYARDd7uiDdbT0IOnJWP7mjL2b68j09xyUUi5TEmZlVYRFhGTXlLIOWW8OopCmUeyA2TYuKCVy4STXEnWofXZEcFJP1iPRFCSojMNJuwSjPqpyfr8Aw)

Our code is being executed in an environment where trying to access any variable throws an error (and there are no built-in functions). But the list of subclasses of `object` is very large, and includes multiple classes that somehow reference the original `builtins` object... The number 81 may stop working in other Python versions (but it can be replaced by something different, and it works in both Python 3.8 and 3.9)

Comment: Wow, that was fast, and not at all my intended solution! I'll post a new fixed version now

Comment: Fixed version: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231421

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3, pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231507/64121)

With direct memory access, nothing is really immutable. Replaces the string in the constant table of the lambda function.

```python
import ctypes

wow = f.__code__.co_consts[2].co_consts[1]
hah = 'hah'
ctypes.memmove(id(wow), id(hah), hah.__sizeof__())
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY5NCsIwEIX3OcXgxgS0VFdScOUxSgk1mdCC-SEdtfUqbrrRrefxNg5042bmzc_7eM93mqiLYZ5fV3Lbw_dk0YGTqhJAeapwRCNjwiBLVWRsrVRKAI4GE1WlgIx0zQEurT_btqpX93hfNQvqk3IfSDJLqrps1LKdv2PvU8wEhqaEgxBsgSO4QmsTLWpdmMgqDDTU--Zv2DWiazt-XXNbi8VeePQ-3lD2VjJIbYAF31lwZebQPzA6rTn3EuAH)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://python.org), cracks [@Bgil Midol's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242866/107299)

```
t%sb
```

Took be a minute to realize that this is a format and not a mod operation

Comment: Yep, totally intended.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231507/100563) - (Incorrect crack)

```python
 f=open(1,'w')
 f.write('hah')
 f.close()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LcwxDoIwFMbxvadoGOS9RAlupomTxyAMtbwGEmyb8kjhLC4sunoebqMBx--fL7_nO8zcercsr5Ht6bLeGrLSAiohOc6KJjLgAzkosYikG0AUkiZDgVUpZCQeo5O9ftwbraos-ZTVO_UJsXMMPwuwKmvc67Ie7HUDz8c85ShskWLHBHmr222a3g8E__sX)

Comment: Ugh apologies for editing on my phone...

Comment: Nope, it has to return from the function.

Comment: Ah yes, missed that!